# When would you use the different git merge strategies?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

From the man page on git-merge, there are a number of merge strategies you can use.

- *resolve* - 
  This can only resolve two heads (i.e. the current branch and another branch you pulled from) using 3-way merge algorithm. It tries to carefully detect criss-cross merge ambiguities and is considered generally safe and fast.
- *recursive* - 
  This can only resolve two heads using 3-way merge algorithm. When there are more than one common ancestors that can be used for 3-way merge, it creates a merged tree of the common ancestors and uses that as the reference tree for the 3-way merge. This has been reported to result in fewer merge conflicts without causing mis-merges by tests done on actual merge commits taken from Linux 2.6 kernel development history. Additionally this can detect and handle merges involving renames. This is the default merge strategy when pulling or merging one branch.
- *octopus* - 
  This resolves more than two-head case, but refuses to do complex merge that needs manual resolution. It is primarily meant to be used for bundling topic branch heads together. This is the default merge strategy when pulling or merging more than one branches.
- *ours* - 
  This resolves any number of heads, but the result of the merge is always the current branch head. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches.
- *subtree* - 
  This is a modified recursive strategy. When merging trees A and B, if B corresponds to a subtree of A, B is first adjusted to match the tree structure of A, instead of reading the trees at the same level. This adjustment is also done to the common ancestor tree.

When should I specify something different than the default?  What scenarios are each best for?

Answer (score 326, accepted):

I'm not familiar with resolve, but I've used the others:

### Recursive

Recursive is the default for non-fast-forward merges. We're all familiar with that one.

### Octopus

I've used octopus when I've had several trees that needed to be merged.  You see this in larger projects where many branches have had independent development and it's all ready to come together into a single head.

An octopus branch merges multiple heads in one commit as long as it can do it cleanly.

For illustration, imagine you have a project that has a master, and then three branches to merge in (call them a, b, and c).

A series of recursive merges would look like this (note that the first merge was a fast-forward, as I didn't force recursion):

[image: series of recursive merges]

However, a single octopus merge would look like this:

```
commit ae632e99ba0ccd0e9e06d09e8647659220d043b9
Merge: f51262e... c9ce629... aa0f25d...
```

[image: octopus merge]

### Ours

Ours == I want to pull in another head, but throw away all of the changes that head introduces.

This keeps the history of a branch without any of the effects of the branch.

(Read: It is not even looked at the changes between those branches. The branches are just merged and nothing is done to the files. If you want to merge in the other branch and every time there is the question "our file version or their version" you can use `git merge -X ours`)

### Subtree

Subtree is useful when you want to merge in another project into a subdirectory of your current project. Useful when you have a library you don't want to include as a submodule.

Comment: So the only real advantage of Ocotopus is to reduce the number of merge commits in the tree?

Comment: You don't need to specify **octopus** merge strategy: it is used automatically if you merge more than two branches (`git merge A B ...`).

Comment: Sorry for going off-topic, but what is the tool that you made those screenshots of? It looks like a really great/pretty visualization of branch history...

Comment: [gitg](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Gitg) for those on linux environment.

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) is free and pretty awesome also.

Comment: Which merge strategy to choose when we have 2 branches: master and another one forked from master. My colleague is working on second branch, I am on master, periodically merging second branch into master, and he continues working in separate branch. I am tired of resolving many merge conflicts in the same places again and again. What to do?

Comment: Similar to @Otto, I'd like to understand what the advantage of an octopus merge is over saying "git merge a", "git merge b" and then "git merge c".

Comment: To answer my own question by quoting the "Git Pocket Guide" available via Google search: "The octopus merge does not have any inherent advantage over simply merging all the topic branches into the master pairwise and reconciling the conflicts there; it accomplishes the same goal and incorporates the same history. However, with a large number of branches, it can make for a cleaner and more easily understood commit graph, and so some people prefer it."

Comment: This hint with `-X ours` is awesome, just saved me an hour of work.

Comment: I think the strategy `ours` would need a bit more explanation. It's basically *meant to be used* in cases where you want to declare that all the changes in one branch should be ignored. This is sometimes required to coordinate bigger distributed projects where *other people may have created* changes based on the branch that should be ignored so they'll get proper conflicts when they try to merge. Had it been called `discard` or `ignore` the actual behavior would have been much easier to understand. Then `-s ours` *could* have been same as `-X ours`.

Answer (score 53):

Actually the only two strategies you would want to choose are **ours** if you want to abandon changes brought by branch, but keep the branch in history, and **subtree** if you are merging independent project into subdirectory of superproject (like 'git-gui' in 'git' repository).

*octopus* merge is used automatically when merging more than two branches.  *resolve* is here mainly for historical reasons, and for when you are hit by *recursive* merge strategy corner cases.

Comment: I had to choose 'resolve' instead of the default 'recursive' for a two-head merge that had fatal git-write-tree errors. 'Resolve' strategy merged cleanly. It may have had to do with moving a lot of files around in the branch being merged.

Comment: @thaddeusmt: Interesting.  Could you please, if at all possible, post bug report about this failure of "recursive" merge strategy to git mailing list?  Thanks in  advance.

Comment: @JakubNarębski I'm not sure how I'd get together enough information to file a meaningful bug report, I'm a n00b with Git, sorry. As I mention in my answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10636464/164439) my *guess* is that had to do with me duplicating changes in both branches, and "resolve" does a better job of skipping the duplicated changes.

Comment: @JakubNarębski by now you can also choose _theirs_, which is according to the manual " the opposite of _ours_. _Theirs_ is neither chosen automatically for you. May you can slightly update your anwser, adding the _theirs_ option

Comment: @SebTu: there is no `theirs` merge strategy (that is `--strategy=theirs`), but there is `theirs` option to the default `recursive` merge strategy (that is `--strategy=recursive --strategy-option=theirs`, or just `-Xtheirs`).

Answer (score 31):

#### "Resolve" vs "Recursive" merge strategy

Recursive is the current default two-head strategy, but after some searching I finally found some info about the "resolve" merge strategy.

Taken from O'Reilly book [Version Control with Git](http://books.google.com/books?id=e9FsGUHjR5sC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=git%20merge%20%22-s%20resolve%22&source=bl&ots=Zi5h3H_bqh&sig=Lp_-I3uOvMbYBcsraQEe6WbFMhU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cPW0T7qzEsae2gWeq9w9&ved=0CGQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=git%20merge%20%22-s%20resolve%22&f=false) ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002L4EXHO)) (paraphrased):

> Originally, "resolve" was the default strategy for Git merges.
>
> In criss-cross merge situations, where there is more than one possible merge basis, the resolve strategy works like this: pick one of the possible merge bases, and hope for the best. This is actually not as bad as it sounds. It often turns out that the users have been working on different parts of the code. In that case, Git detects that it's remerging some changes that are already in place and skips the duplicate changes, avoiding the conflict. Or, if these are slight changes that do cause conflict, at least the conflict should be easy for the developer to handle..

I have successfully merged trees using "resolve" that failed with the default recursive strategy. I was getting `fatal: git write-tree failed to write a tree` errors, and thanks to [this blog post](http://www.tommymorgan.com/2011/04/git-merge-fails-with-fatal-git-write.html) ([mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20110911184425/http://www.tommymorgan.com/2011/04/git-merge-fails-with-fatal-git-write.html)) I tried "-s resolve", which worked. I'm still not exactly sure why... but I think it was because I had duplicate changes in both trees, and resolve "skipped" them properly.

Comment: I am using 3-way merge (p4merge) and I had conflicts written to the .BASE file when the recursive-merge failed. Falling back to resolve-strategy helped in this case.

Answer (score 8):

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), there will be a *new* merge strategy: **ORT** ("**Ostensibly Recursive's Twin**").

```
git merge -s ort
```

This comes from [this thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/CABPp-BFRftNf8hoj8nTDiw+akci=w2qVAgamVDyRw1NUk-QCNA@mail.gmail.com/) from Elijah Newren:

> For now, I'm calling it "Ostensibly Recursive's Twin", or "ort" for short.  >
> At first, people shouldn't be able to notice any difference between it and the current recursive strategy, other than the fact that I think I can make it a bit faster (especially for big repos).
>
> But it should allow me to fix some (admittedly corner case) bugs that are harder to handle in the current design, and I think that a merge that doesn't touch `$GIT_WORK_TREE` or `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` will allow for some fun new features.
> That's the hope anyway.

[Problem](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqd147kpdm.fsf@gitster.mtv.corp.google.com/):

> In the ideal world, we should:
>
> - ask `unpack_trees()` to do "`read-tree -m`" without "`-u`";
> - do all the merge-recursive computations in-core and prepare the
>   resulting index, while keeping the current index intact;
> - compare the current in-core index and the resulting in-core index, and notice the paths that need to be added, updated or removed in the working tree, and ensure that there is no loss of information when the change is reflected to the working tree;
>   E.g. the result wants to create a file where the working tree currently has a directory with non-expendable contents in it, the result wants to remove a file where the working tree file has local modification, etc.;
>   And then finally
> - carry out the working tree update to make it match what the resulting in-core index says it should look like.

Result:

See [commit 14c4586](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14c4586c2dfa94d86d71a60481dd20bc5b56e562) (02 Nov 2020), [commit fe1a21d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe1a21d5267cae88d4312e3595909720717eb31c) (29 Oct 2020), and [commit 47b1e89](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47b1e890e3f7ba57e8c5bc364dcb04d8b2dc1c58), [commit 17e5574](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17e5574b0446836af08136ae269b30767c05b1d7) (27 Oct 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a1f9595](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1f95951efc55c97477e32287b06e204553be5c2), 18 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`merge-ort`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17e5574b0446836af08136ae269b30767c05b1d7): barebones API of new merge strategy with empty implementation
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> This is the beginning of a new merge strategy.
>
> While there are some API differences, and the implementation has some differences in behavior, it is essentially meant as an eventual drop-in replacement for [`merge-recursive.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/17e5574b0446836af08136ae269b30767c05b1d7/merge-recursive.c).
>
> However, it is being built to exist side-by-side with merge-recursive so that we have plenty of time to find out how those differences pan out in the real world while people can still fall back to merge-recursive.
> (Also, I intend to avoid modifying merge-recursive during this process, to keep it stable.)
>
> The primary difference noticable here is that the updating of the working tree and index is not done simultaneously with the merge algorithm, but is a separate post-processing step.
> The new API is designed so that one can do repeated merges (e.g. during a rebase or cherry-pick) and only update the index and working tree one time at the end instead of updating it with every intermediate result.
>
> Also, one can perform a merge between two branches, neither of which match the index or the working tree, without clobbering the index or working tree.

And:

See [commit 848a856](https://github.com/git/git/commit/848a856b136c6aaeb2b7944add318485c6c6d6ae), [commit fd15863](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd15863ec8a90a4c2b4429f5f5de370c8599e700), [commit 23bef2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23bef2e33c3290ae308c2ce37e290a25eb5b97bc), [commit c8c35f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8c35f6a02f3841d4383a5ce4c9d8e426776d151), [commit c12d1f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c12d1f2ac227cbec44be27de83ef07d135f243c2), [commit 727c75b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/727c75b23f25f752810f412e936d420f5c7fee04), [commit 489c85f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/489c85ff43b292cc22ae2e003fad74c75f7ae190), [commit ef52778](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef527787089ce9a5c137ffde24701dfb7fda841c), [commit f06481f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f06481f12732e846c0572a0109e2c5b5684f508a) (26 Oct 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 66c62ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66c62eaec66bb585caabf560a5e1e49cd64e7a1f), 18 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`t6423, t6436`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23bef2e33c3290ae308c2ce37e290a25eb5b97bc): note improved ort handling with dirty files
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> The "recursive" backend relies on `unpack_trees()` to check if unstaged changes would be overwritten by a merge, but `unpack_trees()` does not understand renames -- and once it returns, it has already written many updates to the working tree and index.
> As such, "recursive" had to do a special 4-way merge where it would need to also treat the working copy as an extra source of differences that we had to carefully avoid overwriting and resulting in moving files to new locations to avoid conflicts.
>
> **The "ort" backend, by contrast, does the complete merge inmemory, and only updates the index and working copy as a post-processing step**.
> If there are dirty files in the way, it can simply abort the merge.

> ### [`t6423`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c12d1f2ac227cbec44be27de83ef07d135f243c2): expect improved conflict markers labels in the ort backend
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> Conflict markers carry an extra annotation of the form
> REF-OR-COMMIT:FILENAME
> to help distinguish where the content is coming from, with the `:FILENAME` piece being left off if it is the same for both sides of history (thus only renames with content conflicts carry that part of the annotation).
>
> However, there were cases where the `:FILENAME` annotation was accidentally left off, due to merge-recursive's every-codepath-needs-a-copy-of-all-special-case-code format.

> ### [`t6404, t6423`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/727c75b23f25f752810f412e936d420f5c7fee04): expect improved rename/delete handling in ort backend
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> When a file is renamed and has content conflicts, merge-recursive does not have some stages for the old filename and some stages for the new filename in the index; instead it copies all the stages corresponding to the old filename over to the corresponding locations for the new filename, so that there are three higher order stages all corresponding to the new filename.
>
> Doing things this way makes it easier for the user to access the different versions and to resolve the conflict (no need to manually '[`git rm`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/727c75b23f25f752810f412e936d420f5c7fee04/Documentation/git-rm.txt) '<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm))</sup> the old version as well as '[`git add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/727c75b23f25f752810f412e936d420f5c7fee04/Documentation/git-add.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> the new one).
>
> rename/deletes should be handled similarly -- there should be two stages for the renamed file rather than just one.
> We do not want to destabilize merge-recursive right now, so instead update relevant tests to have different expectations depending on whether the "`recursive`" or "`ort`" merge strategies are in use.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), Preparation for a new merge strategy.

See [commit 848a856](https://github.com/git/git/commit/848a856b136c6aaeb2b7944add318485c6c6d6ae), [commit fd15863](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd15863ec8a90a4c2b4429f5f5de370c8599e700), [commit 23bef2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23bef2e33c3290ae308c2ce37e290a25eb5b97bc), [commit c8c35f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8c35f6a02f3841d4383a5ce4c9d8e426776d151), [commit c12d1f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c12d1f2ac227cbec44be27de83ef07d135f243c2), [commit 727c75b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/727c75b23f25f752810f412e936d420f5c7fee04), [commit 489c85f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/489c85ff43b292cc22ae2e003fad74c75f7ae190), [commit ef52778](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef527787089ce9a5c137ffde24701dfb7fda841c), [commit f06481f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f06481f12732e846c0572a0109e2c5b5684f508a) (26 Oct 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 66c62ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66c62eaec66bb585caabf560a5e1e49cd64e7a1f), 18 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`merge tests`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef527787089ce9a5c137ffde24701dfb7fda841c): expect improved directory/file conflict handling in ort
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> [`merge-recursive.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ef527787089ce9a5c137ffde24701dfb7fda841c/merge-recursive.c) is built on the idea of running `unpack_trees()` and then "doing minor touch-ups" to get the result.
> Unfortunately, `unpack_trees()` was run in an update-as-it-goes mode, leading [`merge-recursive.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ef527787089ce9a5c137ffde24701dfb7fda841c/merge-recursive.c) to follow suit and end up with an immediate evaluation and fix-it-up-as-you-go design.
>
> Some things like directory/file conflicts are not well representable in the index data structure, and required special extra code to handle.
> But then when it was discovered that rename/delete conflicts could also be involved in directory/file conflicts, the special directory/file conflict handling code had to be copied to the rename/delete codepath.
> ...and then it had to be copied for modify/delete, and for rename/rename(1to2) conflicts, ...and yet it still missed some.
> Further, when it was discovered that there were also file/submodule conflicts and submodule/directory conflicts, we needed to copy the special submodule handling code to all the special cases throughout the codebase.
>
> And then it was discovered that our handling of directory/file conflicts was suboptimal because it would create untracked files to store the contents of the conflicting file, which would not be cleaned up if someone were to run a '[`git merge --abort`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ef527787089ce9a5c137ffde24701dfb7fda841c/Documentation/git-merge.txt#L95)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---abort))</sup> or '[`git rebase --abort`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ef527787089ce9a5c137ffde24701dfb7fda841c/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L250)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---abort))</sup>.
>
> It was also difficult or scary to try to add or remove the index entries corresponding to these files given the directory/file conflict in the index.
> But changing [`merge-recursive.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ef527787089ce9a5c137ffde24701dfb7fda841c/merge-recursive.c) to handle these correctly was a royal pain because there were so many sites in the code with similar but not identical code for handling directory/file/submodule conflicts that would all need to be updated.
>
> I have worked hard to push all directory/file/submodule conflict handling in merge-ort through a single codepath, and avoid creating untracked files for storing tracked content (it does record things at alternate paths, but makes sure they have higher-order stages in the index).

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), the merge backend "done right" starts to emerge.
Example:

See [commit 6d37ca2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d37ca21651408b6d29b86a67d0179eb98629fd8) (11 Nov 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 89422d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89422d29b1d63004683aaa6d11faa65ba734d46f), [commit ef2b369](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef2b369387004f4f11497a55174d0d9859549054), [commit 70912f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70912f66de751b2f1af145887dc64c9c0d06de36), [commit 6681ce5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6681ce5cf6a869aa73cfe56d041dce133262587a), [commit 9fefce6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9fefce68dc85d96781090f86c067d83f7c50b617), [commit bb470f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb470f4e13e90889030d48f618ded5c0961943a3), [commit ee4012d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee4012dcf962fa26ae83d1e7ff28263b9d2d1452), [commit a9945bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9945bba600914bc8feb7aa52dce7b8e41237649), [commit 8adffaa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8adffaa818d17595b23959e995ad395c8cd0b0be), [commit 6a02dd9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a02dd90c99c59eada5e5b80e7140e56c1d4a2b0), [commit 291f29c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/291f29caf6b045576f9953f0ea41fc8367966750), [commit 98bf984](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98bf98416726430b6cbc8670725f008588e478a7), [commit 34e557a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34e557af5469299453f63d3594d5b392a09937d1), [commit 885f006](https://github.com/git/git/commit/885f0063e9962068d381ca5256ca49070bb2480c), [commit d2bc199](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2bc1994f363ac2049da0cdd0b8a7bed61eeaab0), [commit 0c0d705](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c0d705b5cba39c70b01b8b21e2c4d3ca014daf3), [commit c801717](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8017176ac8fb5cc85ca8742bbdeec8943427340), [commit e4171b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4171b1b6d32a147638f52c3199477d3ea161b3e), [commit 231e2dd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/231e2dd49d11c1ea5d19956920651bd3a90ccfce), [commit 5b59c3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b59c3db059d85306ebeb680c4d322a69ee29fde) (13 Dec 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f9d29da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9d29daba64ae2c81ed62d0c1f4c5e4493247f6b), 06 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`merge-ort`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef2b369387004f4f11497a55174d0d9859549054): add implementation of `record_conflicted_index_entries()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> After `checkout()`, the working tree has the appropriate contents, and the index matches the working copy.
> That means that all unmodified and cleanly merged files have correct index entries, but conflicted entries need to be updated.
>
> We do this by looping over the conflicted entries, marking the existing index entry for the path with `CE_REMOVE`, adding new higher order staged for the path at the end of the index (ignoring normal index sort order), and then at the end of the loop removing the `CE_REMOVED-marked` cache entries and sorting the index.

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), rename detection is added to the "ORT" merge strategy.

See [commit 6fcccbd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6fcccbd75556d1dcc80493f6eb51109f53a5dc83), [commit f1665e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1665e69188f54c941f9bf10ed388a72a91cc2a1), [commit 35e47e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35e47e3514b5129e6075a67fa9f4659da2f1a1a1), [commit 2e91ddd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e91ddd24e7240460fd2a9aee1962345ed858b6b), [commit 53e88a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/53e88a03539db70a7e990489784400b0b2916fa9), [commit af1e56c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af1e56c49e61a39d5a7d78cecb97f350b5a3834a) (15 Dec 2020), and [commit c2d267d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2d267df0215d49f06638463889465389134021a), [commit 965a7bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/965a7bc21c6bb11fb15eb798fd472ec9deb5e3fa), [commit f39d05c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f39d05ca2637dfcbf0498824d06e7854427936a5), [commit e1a124e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e1a124e8dc3d21afedc80cc2842d705c1d5a90c9), [commit 864075e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/864075ec433644e5908589fe79f8b3296f896867) (14 Dec 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2856089](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2856089e367cc126f70d0a3d6d6ff5290d204f2e), 25 Jan 2021)</sup>

Example:

> ### [`merge-ort`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1665e69188f54c941f9bf10ed388a72a91cc2a1): add implementation of normal rename handling
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> Implement handling of normal renames.
> This code replaces the following from `merge-recurisve.c`:
>
> - the code relevant to `RENAME_NORMAL` in `process_renames()`
> - the `RENAME_NORMAL` case of `process_entry()`
>
> Also, there is some shared code from [`merge-recursive.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f1665e69188f54c941f9bf10ed388a72a91cc2a1/merge-recursive.c) for multiple different rename cases which we will no longer need for this case (or other rename cases):
>
> - `handle_rename_normal()`
> - `setup_rename_conflict_info()`
>
> The consolidation of four separate codepaths into one is made possible by a change in design: `process_renames()` tweaks the `conflict_info` entries within `opt->priv->paths` such that `process_entry()` can then handle all the non-rename conflict types (directory/file, modify/delete, etc.) orthogonally.
>
> This means we're much less likely to miss special implementation of some kind of combination of conflict types (see commits brought in by [66c62ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66c62eaec66bb585caabf560a5e1e49cd64e7a1f) ("Merge branch 'en/merge-tests'", 2020-11-18, Git v2.30.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66c62eaec66bb585caabf560a5e1e49cd64e7a1f) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/faefdd61ec7c7f6f3c8c9907891465ac9a2a1475)), especially [commit ef52778](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef527787089ce9a5c137ffde24701dfb7fda841c) ("merge tests: expect improved directory/file conflict handling in ort", 2020-10-26, Git v2.30.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66c62eaec66bb585caabf560a5e1e49cd64e7a1f) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/faefdd61ec7c7f6f3c8c9907891465ac9a2a1475)) for more details).
>
> That, together with letting worktree/index updating be handled orthogonally in the `merge_switch_to_result()` function, dramatically simplifies the code for various special rename cases.
>
> (To be fair, the code for handling normal renames wasn't all that complicated beforehand, but it's still much simpler now.)

And, still with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), oRT merge strategy learns more support for merge conflicts.

See [commit 4ef88fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ef88fc3a8d402de272c6bfa36538bd8e4cdd439), [commit 4204cd5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4204cd591b62f3e184f617d01b282b9847298dbd), [commit 70f19c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70f19c7fced2ec49fd9bca827370835d84d782c7), [commit c73cda7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c73cda76b104795d1455ecbf031a18045ab37a84), [commit f591c47](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f591c4724615b2fc1e4dc3d6bfe5da96a88eacbe), [commit 62fdec1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62fdec17a111e419b750938d24b6d65e3076b76d), [commit 991bbdc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/991bbdcab94d93c2a325c4ce74cff139f0f49d97), [commit 5a1a1e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a1a1e8ea9fdd4a575c711b91f176838ea502e44), [commit 23366d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23366d2aa97544fe76bc86964f4493b7b89e7b22), [commit 0ccfa4e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ccfa4e5d8489abe7c5d3fe29b68e4fe0cae6fe1) (01 Jan 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b65b9ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b65b9ff1ff8a809246cc6bd8ad9051b28e5bf330), 05 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`merge-ort`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ef88fc3a8d402de272c6bfa36538bd8e4cdd439): add handling for different types of files at same path
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> Add some handling that explicitly considers collisions of the following types:
>
> - file/submodule
> - file/symlink
> - submodule/symlink> Leaving them as conflicts at the same path are hard for users to resolve, so move one or both of them aside so that they each get their own path.
>
> Note that in the case of recursive handling (i.e.
> `call_depth > 0`), we can just use the merge base of the two merge bases as the merge result much like we do with modify/delete conflicts, binary files, conflicting submodule values, and so on.

Comment: is ORT going to replace "recursive" as the default merge strategy?

Comment: @UndefinedBehavior as the first commit message in the answer suggests, yes, it will replace eventually the recursive one. The same commit message suggests that, for now, it exists side-by-side with "recursive".

Comment: @UndefinedBehavior I have edited the answer to add the git mailing-list thread which illustrates the origin of this new merge strategy.

Comment: @UndefinedBehavior yes, in git 2.34

Comment: @UndefinedBehavior Indeed. To be released... next Monday! (Nov, 15th, 2021)