# Git: Merge to master while automatically choosing to overwrite master files with branch

Tags: git, merge, branch

I am using Git to track my documentation latex source. I want to keep the master branch full of documents that are suitable for end user release, so when someone needs something, i can just switch to the master branch, compile and hand out the document.

I make new branches when a manual needs a major update. But, when the manual is approved, it needs to get merged back into the master. When merging from *branch* into *master*, I would like to pass some command to Git to say, "forget the merging, just use the the file from *branch* to overwrite the file in *master*." Is there a way to do this? Specifically, I want to avoid opening up a merge tool every time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could do an interactive merge and spoon feed it (with `yes`) whatever the answer is when it asks what to do...

Comment: @r-martinho-fernandes: What's the interactive merge command?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

To disregard `master`, when you have `branch` checked out then:

```
git merge master --strategy=ours
```

http://schacon.github.com/git/git-merge.html

As <strike>'Computer Linguist'</strike> [Lilith River](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166893/lilith-river)
commented, this will "ignore everything from 'master', even if it has changes to new, independent files".  So if you are not the OP and want a more safe merge that does not as the OP says "forget the merging", then use this excellent safe command from [Lilith River](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166893/lilith-river), and upvote his comment up so he gets credit.

```
git merge -s recursive -X theirs <branch>
```

Comment: From here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366860/when-would-you-use-the-different-git-merge-strategies, this says:  Ours == I want to pull in another head, but throw away all of the changes that head introduces.
So is opposite of what OP wanted.

Comment: If you're in branch and you `git merge master --strategy=ours` then it keeps branch's changes.  (what OP wants)  But if you are in master and use "ours" then it keeps master's. (opposite)

Comment: From my reading of the question, Mica wants to merge branch into master, keeping the state of branch i.e. `git merge branch` onto master, so --strategy=ours is the opposite of what he wants

Comment: From branch 'master', running `git merge -s recursive -X theirs branch` will resolve all conflicts by picking the 'branch' version. using -s ours will ignore everything from 'master', even if it has changes to new, independent files.

Comment: OP wants to target the merge to `master`, but @Robert's answer targets onto `branch`

Comment: This answer became a lot confusing to me. That command are doing the opposite.

Comment: Instead of the **second command** here, isn't it sufficient to do `git merge branch` while on master? IIRC it will be simply Fast-Forwarded. Am I missing something?

Comment: for anyone who is still confused who wants to overwrite all files on master with those on the branch (regardless of whether or not there are conflicts), see this answer on a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2862938/1179207

Answer (score 15):

In version 1.7.1 of Git, you can use "-Xtheirs" to merge in the branch itself.

For example, if you start in your master branch, 
starting in master

`git checkout -b editBranch

-- edit your files --

git add .

git commit -m "Updated the files"

git checkout master

git merge -Xtheirs editBranch`

Another way that I've seen to do this based off [this post](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=121637513604413&w=2) is to do a hard reset off the editBranch. For example:

`git checkout -b editBranch

-- edit your files --

git add .

git commit -m "Updated the files"

git checkout master

git reset --hard editBranch`

I think this second way might be the better play, but I haven't had a chance to play around with it enough yet.

Comment: thanks. I'll have to update git at home, and check this out. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this with the 'ours' merge strategy:

```
git checkout branch
git merge -s ours master
```

But this doesn't do exactly what you want: it override the contents of the *current* working branch `branch` and what you want is to get the same contents onto `master`.  What you really want is a merge strategy `theirs`, and for that I point you at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/git-merge-s-ours-what-about-their) for a way to do it.  In practice what it boils down to is resetting `master` to point at `branch`.