# How to replace master branch in Git, entirely, from another branch?

Tags: git, merge, git-branch

I have two branches in my Git repository:

1. `master`
2. `seotweaks` (created originally from `master`)

I created `seotweaks` with the intention of quickly merging it back into `master`. However, that was three months ago and the code in this branch is 13 versions ahead of `master`.

It has effectively become our working master branch as all the code in `master` is more or less obsolete now.

Very bad practice I know, lesson learned.

Do you know how I can replace all of the contents of the `master` branch with those in `seotweaks`?

I could just delete everything in `master` and merge, but this does not feel like best practice.

Comment: Also,  this question is better worded and is missing the confusion caused by the "Extra" comment added to the question after answers had started.

Comment: There is a simple way using checkout, if and only if you are not worried about commit histories of seotweaks.
Switch to master branch first, then run,

`git checkout seotweaks -- *`
then run,
`git commit -m "Replaced contents of master with seotweaks"`
finally run
`git push`

Answer (score 3582, accepted):

You should be able to use the “ours” merge strategy to overwrite master with seotweaks like this:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout seotweaks
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge seotweaks
```

The first two steps are a useful precaution to ensure your local copy of master is up-to-date. The result should be that your master is now essentially seotweaks.

(`-s ours` is short for `--strategy=ours`)

From [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) about the 'ours' strategy:

> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches. Note that this is different from the -Xours option to the recursive merge strategy.

Update from comments: If you get fatal: `refusing to merge unrelated histories`, then change the second line to this: `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories -s ours master`

Comment: @Joel Berger, the recursive merge options will mix the two branches, favoring "theirs" or "ours" only on conflict.  So you'll get changes from both branches.

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I do "git merge -s ours master" from the other branch, I get "Already up-to-date." Anything else I can try?

Comment: @elsurudo It's probably not an error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/634575/240633

Comment: Since I am working on remote branches, I need to push after every merge?

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem the original posted did and this approach replaced master with my desired branch within 2 minutes.  Thank you.

Comment: the rename strategy posted by @ZelluX below better solves this problem.  This answer will just merge a cleaned up branch on top of your existing master

Comment: @ergosys Is there any advantage to this approach than ZelluX's method of renaming the branches? This one looks rather misleading later on when you look at the merge, but perhaps the renaming approach has a disadvantage?

Comment: Other than VonC's answer, which raises some issues, you don't retain any non-conflicting changes from the old master when you rename.  You may not mind this, depends on the situation.

Comment: I like this solution because it keeps changes locally to be verified before overriding master!!!

Comment: Why are steps 3 and 4 needed when you already replaced the master branch ins step 1 and 2

Comment: Worked for me.  Remember to push *both* branches if you're trying to fix a remote repo like github or bitbucket.

Comment: This preserved all the commits on master :( Did I do it wrong?

Comment: Did those steps - looked like did something locally, but it didn't.  Luckily, I made a copy of my working dir first on the newer-branch - did a compare between that and the 'master' branch I supposedly updated.  Nothing had been updated (typical git).  Erased the files on the master-branch's dir (except .git), replaced it with the work in the dir with the newer-branch work, then git add-ed and committed - done.  Lesson: make full-backups before 'git' anything.

Comment: this does not work. I have to now resolve conflicts. Does not replace master. No different then merging 2 branches.

Comment: this would merge master into your branch ?? which is not what you want - you want to entirely replace master with another branch - or did I misunderstand ?

Comment: I did this and did git push after. Effectively the master commits disappeared and was subsituted by the branches commits. IS there a way to reverse these commands?

Comment: @Renato you can see if you can revert to a previous state using reflog.  See http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html

Comment: @elsurudo after renaming, simplest solution -  
push your local develop branch "master" to a remote branch "master"

```git push origin master:master```

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936652/git-push-wont-do-anything-everything-up-to-date

Comment: This approach worked great for me.  We had a beta branch that was being treated as master, and a master branch that hadn't been touched in over a year.  The only thing i did a little different was a git push before i merged beta into master.  "git checkout beta" -> "git merge -s ours master" -> "git push" -> "git checkout master" -> "git merge beta" -> "git push"

Comment: Most simply, assuming you do not care about losing master you could run `git push -f origin seotweaks:master`

Comment: To avoid the need for a commit message:  `git merge -s ours --no-commit master`

Comment: When I do the second step I get `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`. What do I do now?

Comment: But why is the merge commit message `Merge branch 'master' into other` instead of `Merge branch 'other' into master`? And why is this commit on both of the branches? It doesn't make sense for the merge to be on the `other` branch, as this branch should be the one that gets merged in `master`.

Comment: From what I understand, this actually merged the `master` branch into the `other` branch, and then fast-forwards the `master` branch.

Comment: If you get `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`, then change the second line to this: `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories -s ours master`

Comment: Does this approach preserve the history of the original master?

Comment: It is still merging 2 branches histories... I want to replace `master` entirely with `seotweaks`...

Comment: This can not be the answer, that is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2862606/415078

Comment: Not a good answer. This will still merge changes from master into your new branch and have unpredictable results. It's best to do the rename as stated below.

Comment: Still don't get how this thing works, lol. After first merge the `seotweaks` actually stays the same and master is the same. So after second merge master should contain both changes, isn't it? Does that last merge commit negate the master changes?

Comment: Type `:q` then press `enter` to save the commit file after `git merge -s ours master`.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-ours . It will not work always, to quote the source ```Changes from the other tree that do not conflict with our side are reflected in the merge result.``` It did not work for me, as I had cleanly merging commits in my branch which was being overwritten.

Comment: @NiharGht Your quote is from the recursive ours which is different. Look a bit further down for the documentation about only ours option.

Comment: Worked really well for me. Just had to remember that my 'master' branch was named 'main'.

Comment: Don't forget to ```git push``` at the end

Answer (score 637):

What about using git branch -m to rename the master branch to another one, then rename seotweaks branch to master?  Something like this:

```
git branch -m master old-master
git branch -m seotweaks master
git push -f origin master
```

**This might remove commits in origin master**, please check your origin master before running `git push -f origin master`.

Comment: Sorry, when I run this, the changes happen only locally. How can I get this to effect the remote branches? Thanks

Comment: @Jason: Try `git push -f origin master`

Comment: This is probably the best way to do a forced update after ensuring your master can be completely replaced

Comment: you can just do it in two steps: git branch -m oldbranch newbranch; git checkout mynewmaster; git checkout -b master;  .... well, two anyway :-)

Comment: It might be worth explaining that this answer possibly removes commits that were in the original `master` branch.  While ergosys' solution does a proper merge and so retains all history in `master`.

Comment: Crap I just lost all commits in the original master.

Comment: I also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13307342/339803 using `theirs`

Comment: @moberme you can do `git checkout old-master && git push origin old-master` to create a branch with the old master.

Comment: Finalize with `git push origin :seotweaks` to remove the old ref from origin

Comment: If you use this method and want to keep both branches (for example if you wanted to force push code from `staging` to replace `master`, but want to keep both branches after), just rename both branches to their original names after force push, and right after that do `git checkout master` and run `git fetch --all` and `git reset --hard origin/master`. This will force your local `master` history to align with remote's.

Comment: This worked on gitlab. You have to run following before you do this. `git checkout seotweaks`

Comment: This doesn't actually work...Just really messed up my repo

Comment: downvote for just renaming branches not merging

Comment: This is what I was looking for, to actually replace master in its entirety instead of merging (and the title does ask "How to replace master branch"). But instead of the final `git push -f origin master` I did instead `git branch -u origin/master` to set the upstream. In my case the changes to remove were not in the remote.

Comment: @Daniel brings up a good point, to really do this you need to add `git branch -u origin/master` to the mix if the original branch is already tracked by a remote.

Comment: Now after following the answer I'm left with master & old-master on my local and origin/seotweaks & origin/master on my remote. I want to keep both branches in both local and remote. How do I rename the branches and align them to track each other. I'm new to git, help me out with exact commands. THank you.

Answer (score 90):

You can rename/remove master on remote, but this will be an issue if lots of people have based their work on the remote master branch and have pulled that branch in their local repo.
That might not be the case here since everyone seems to be working on branch '`seotweaks`'.

In that case you can:
`git remote --show` may not work.
(Make a [`git remote show`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) to check how your remote is declared within your local repo. I will assume '`origin`')
(Regarding GitHub, [house9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317989/house9) comments: "I had to do one additional step, click the '`Admin`' button on GitHub and set the '`Default Branch`' to something other than '`master`', then put it back afterwards")

```
git branch -m master master-old  # rename master on local
git push origin :master          # delete master on remote
git push origin master-old       # create master-old on remote
git checkout -b master seotweaks # create a new local master on top of seotweaks
git push origin master           # create master on remote
```

But again:

- if other users try to pull while master is deleted on remote, their pulls will fail ("`no such ref on remote`")
- when `master` is recreated on remote, a pull will attempt to merge that new `master` on their local (now old) `master`: lots of conflicts. They actually need to `reset --hard` their local master to the `remote/master` branch they will fetch, and forget about their current `master`.

---

Update/Note 2022:

- `master` would nowodays be named `main`
- git checkout is [obsolete since Git 2.23 (Q3 2019)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309): use [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) for branch operation.

```bash
    git branch -m main main-old  # rename main on local
    git push origin :main          # delete main on remote
    git push origin main-old       # create main-old on remote
    git switch -c main seotweaks # create a new local main on top of seotweaks
    git push origin main           # create main on remote
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, when I run 'git push remote :master' I get an error - 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository.

Comment: @Jason: I changed that to 'origin' which might be the default name given to your remote repo.

Comment: @VonC: I'm trying to do that on git-hub repository, but when trying to perform 'git push origin :master' I get a message '[remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)'. As for why I'm doing that... basically I severely mixed up things, importing two times the same patches through github interface and command line push, then getting everything back to work by manual merge. After that I also created another branch with a clean history, but too late... anyway. As it's on my personal experimental repository I should be the only one impacted.

Comment: @kriss: GitHub will refuse by default any push rewriting/removing history, unless you force the push: `git push -f origin :master`.

Comment: thanks this was a big help; I had to do one additional step, click the 'Admin' button on github and set the 'Default Branch' to something other than 'master', then put it back afterwards

Comment: @house9: good point. I have edited my answer to include that step.

Answer (score 52):

Since `seotweaks` was originally created as a branch from `master`, merging it back in is a good idea. However if you are in a situation where one of your branches is not really a branch from `master` or your history is so different that you just want to obliterate the `master` branch in favor of the new branch that you've been doing the work on you can do this:

```
git push [-f] origin seotweaks:master
```

This is especially helpful if you are getting this error:

```
! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
```

And you are not using GitHub and don't have access to the "Administration" tab to change the default branch for your remote repository. Furthermore, this won't cause down time or race conditions as you may encounter by deleting master:

```
git push origin :master
```

Comment: Does not work on Heroku:  ! [rejected]        <new_branch> -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '<some_git>.git'

Comment: git push -f origin seotweaks:master worked for me

Comment: This was by far the easiest way for me to get extensive changes on a working branch, with many difficult conflicts (due to folders being deleted and renamed), back onto master. I don't know if this is appropriate for every case (probably not), but it totally worked for me just getting everything off a branch I was done with back onto master (the working branch remains after the operation, but both branches appear to now have the same commits).

Comment: How does the `master` git history looks like after `force push`? Does it overwrite all files on `master` even when they weren't changed on `seotweaks`?

Answer (score 9):

I found this to be the best way of doing this (I had an issue with my server not letting me delete).

On the server that hosts the `origin` repository, type the following from a directory inside the repository:

```
git config receive.denyDeleteCurrent ignore
```

On your workstation:

```
git branch -m master vabandoned                 # Rename master on local
git branch -m newBranch master                  # Locally rename branch newBranch to master
git push origin :master                         # Delete the remote's master
git push origin master:refs/heads/master        # Push the new master to the remote
git push origin abandoned:refs/heads/abandoned  # Push the old master to the remote
```

Back on the server that hosts the `origin` repository:

```
git config receive.denyDeleteCurrent true
```

Credit to the author of blog post http://www.mslinn.com/blog/?p=772

Comment: For me master branch was the default branch so I changed default branch as 'develop' branch and deleted master branch and created again master from desired branch. Later if you want you can make 'master' branch again your default branch.

Comment: The link is broken, *"Access Denied"*.

Comment: Shame. I think the blogs do exist on his site still. Just a broken link :(

Comment: It changed. Now it shows an index of posts (and they seem to be accessible).