# Git push won't do anything (everything up-to-date)

Tags: git, dvcs

I'm trying to update a Git repository on GitHub. I made a bunch of changes, added them, committed then attempted to do a `git push`. The response tells me that everything is up to date, but clearly it's not.

```
git remote show origin
```

responds with the repository I'd expect.

Why is Git telling me the repository is up to date when there are local commits that aren't visible on the repository?

```
  [searchgraph]  git status
# On branch develop
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       Capfile
#       config/deploy.rb
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

  [searchgraph]  git add .

  [searchgraph]  git status
# On branch develop
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   Capfile
#       new file:   config/deploy.rb
#

  [searchgraph]  git commit -m "Added Capistrano deployment"
[develop 12e8af7] Added Capistrano deployment
 2 files changed, 26 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 Capfile
 create mode 100644 config/deploy.rb

  [searchgraph]  git push
Everything up-to-date

  [searchgraph]  git status
# On branch develop
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: Also make sure you're pushing to the correct branch.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

`git push` doesn't push all of your local branches: how would it know which remote branches to push them to? It only pushes local branches which have been configured to push to a particular remote branch.

On my version of Git (1.6.5.3), when I run `git remote show origin` it actually prints out which branches are configured for push:

```
Local refs configured for 'git push':
  master pushes to master (up to date)
  quux   pushes to quux   (fast forwardable)
```

**Q. But I could push to `master` without worrying about all this!**

When you `git clone`, by default it sets up your local `master` branch to push to the remote's `master` branch (locally referred to as `origin/master`), so if you only commit on `master`, then a simple `git push` will always push your changes back.

However, from the output snippet you posted, you're on a branch called `develop`, which I'm guessing hasn't been set up to push to anything.  So `git push` without arguments won't push commits on that branch.

When it says "Everything up-to-date", it means "all the branches you've told me how to push are up to date".

**Q. So how can I push my commits?**

If what you want to do is put your changes from `develop` into `origin/master`, then you should probably merge them into your local `master` then push that:

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
git push             # will push 'master'
```

If what you want is to create a `develop` branch on the remote, separate from `master`, then supply arguments to `git push`:

```
git push origin develop
```

That will: create a new branch on the remote called `develop`; *and* bring that branch up to date with your local `develop` branch; *and* set `develop` to push to `origin/develop` so that in future, `git push` without arguments *will* push `develop` automatically.

If you want to push your local `develop` to a remote branch called something *other than* `develop`, then you can say:

```
git push origin develop:something-else
```

However, that form *won't* set up `develop` to always push to `origin/something-else` in future; it's a one-shot operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot , your git push origin develop:something-else has given answer to question i was not able to get for a while.

Comment: In my case `git push origin x` was still not setting up branch x to be pushed in the future. It was due to a specific pushspec in `.gitconfig` `[remote "origin"]` section which was causing git's behavior.

Comment: Using only `git push origin` I had this problem, using your example `git push origin develop` and accommodating it to my master branch `git push origin master` the problem was solved, thanks

Comment: If you ever get the fantastic idea of `aha so probably if I do git push :target_branch it will assume I want to push my current branch` - no, it will delete the remote branch

Comment: This helped. Thank you

Comment: I tried `git push origin some_branch --force` but it always returned `Everything is up-to-date` message. So I was searching for that and stumbled upon your comment that said `git push origin develop:some_branch --force` and this was what I was missing.  Thanks!

Comment: git doesn't always automatically _track_ (automatically push to the remote branch). the information it uses for this is stored in the git config file (`.git/config` for the curious). to add the connection, add `-u` to the `git push` command.  `-u` is the shorthand for the `--set-upstream` flag, it specifically tells git which remote branch belongs to your local one

Answer (score 36):

This happened to me when my SourceTree application crashed during staging. And on the command line, it seemed like the previous `git add` had been corrupted. If this is the case, try:

```
git init
git add -A
git commit -m 'Fix bad repo'
git push
```

On the last command, you might need to set the branch.

```
git push --all origin master
```

Bear in mind that this is enough if you haven't done any branching or any of that sort. In that case, make sure you push to the correct branch like `git push origin develop`.

Answer (score 20):

Please try going to the last commit and then do `git push origin HEAD:master`.

Comment: This actually worked. Would you like to explain *why* it worked?

Comment: Textually from docs: `Push the current branch to the remote ref matching master in the origin repository. This form is convenient to push the current branch without thinking about its local name.`

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: I compared how my repo is configured and all branches looked the same. Yet, in one branch I couldn't simply use `git push` :/ This worked for me as well: `git push origin HEAD:my_branch_name`.

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
git push --all origin
```

Comment: this pushes the commits to separate branches on the repo, not from one branch into master.

Comment: This helped me. I entered `git push origin/myBranch` instead of `git push origin myBranch` and commit was not in repository... `git diff` or `git status` - nothing to commit... after `git push --all origin` was everything ok... commit in repo appears... in right branch. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Right now, it appears as you are on the develop branch. Do you have a develop branch on your origin? If not, try `git push origin develop`. `git push` will work once it knows about a develop branch on your origin.

As further reading, I'd have a look at the [git-push man pages](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html), in particular, the examples section.

Answer (score 5):

For my case, none of other solutions worked. I had to do a backup of new modified files (shown with `git status`), and run a `git reset --hard`. This allowed me to realign with the remote server. Adding new modified files, and running

```
git add .
git commit -am "my comment"
git push
```

Did the trick. I hope this helps someone, as a "last chance" solution.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Sam Stokes. According to his answer you can solve the problem with different way (I used this way). After updating your develop directory you should reinitialize it

```
git init
```

Then you can commit and push updates to master

Comment: Thanks!
In my case, 
type: `git init`
and open a new command tab, type:
`git push origin branch_name`

Answer (score 3):

To be specific, if you want to merge something to master, you can follow the below steps.

```
git add --all // If you want to stage all changes other options also available
git commit -m "Your commit message"
git push // By default when it clone is sets your origin to master or you would have set sometime with git push -u origin master.
```

It's a common practice in the pull request model create to a new local branch and then push that branch to remote. For that you need to mention where you want to push your changes at remote.
You can do this by mentioning remote at the time of push.

```
git push origin develop // It will create a remote branch with name "develop".
```

If you want to create a branch other than your local branch name you can do that with the following command.

```
git push origin develop:some-other-name
```

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I `^C` in the middle of a `git push` to GitHub. GitHub did not show that the changes had been made, however.

To fix it, I made a change to my working tree, committed, and then pushed again. It worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me. I just re-committed the changes, and then it pushed.

Answer (score 2):

Follow The Steps:

1. `git log`
2. `git remote -v [Check Wheather any Origin is there or not]`
3. [IF NO ORIGIN]
   `git remote add origin yourOriginName`
   eg: `git remote add origin https://github.com/vikaskumar27071990/RandomCodes.git`
4. `git status`
5. `git push -u origin master`

(IF YOU GETTING ERROR LIKE **master** set up to track remote branch **master** from **origin**  THEN FOLLOW BELOW POINTS)

6. `git init`
7. `git add -A`
8. `git commit -m 'Fix bad repo'`
9. `git push`

On the last command, you might need to set the branch.

`git push --all origin master`

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you could try the following. You don't have to go to `master`; you can directly force push the changes from your branch itself.

As explained above, when you do a rebase, you are changing the history on your branch. As a result, if you try to do a normal `git push` after a rebase, Git will reject it because there isn't a direct path from the commit on the server to the commit on your branch. Instead, you'll need to use the `-f` or `--force` flag to tell Git that yes, you really know what you're doing. When doing force pushes, it is highly recommended that you set your `push.default` config setting to simple, which is the default in Git 2.0. To make sure that your configuration is correct, run:

```
$ git config --global push.default simple
```

Once it's correct, you can just run:

```
$ git push -f
```

And check your pull request. It should be updated!

Go to bottom of *[How to Rebase a Pull Request](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/How-to-Rebase-a-Pull-Request)* for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many methods including defined here.
What I got is,

- Make sure the name of repository is valid. The best way is to copy the link from repository site and paste in git bash.
- Make sure you have commited the selected files.

  ```
  git commit -m "Your commit here"
  ```
- If both steps don't work, try

  `git push -u -f origin master`

Answer (score 1):

The problem could also be that the local branch does not have an upstream.

use:

```
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

You are setting up what branch you are pushing the files to.

Comment: just a note for anyone comparing answers - `-u` is the shorthand for the `--set-upstream` flag, and it specifically tells git to which remote branch belongs to your local one

Answer (score 1):

if are adding new project to github you can use below steps :

```
rm -rf .git/
git init
git remote add origin https://repository.remote.url
git add .
git commit -m “Commit message here”.
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: in recent times you might want to use the SSH url  when you `git remote add origin` (starts with eg `git@github.com:` and a default `main` branch. also be wary of the `-f` flag - this means you're doing a _forced_ push and overwrite the existing branch on the remote.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once I tried to push from a new branch and I used `git push origin master` instead.
You should either:

- Use: `git push origin your_new_branch` if you want that this
  branch occurs too in the remote repo.
- Else check out to your master branch merge things then push to from master to git repo with `git merge origin master`.

> Recap: the point here is that you should check out where you offer on
>   the **second parameter** for git merge. So if you are in the master use
>   master as the second parameter if you are in the new_branch use this
>   as the second parameter if you want to keep this branch in the remote
>   repo else opt for the second option above instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to delete all remotes (there were multiple for some unexplained reason), add the remote again, and commit with -f.

```
$ git remote
origin
upstream

$ git remote remove upstream
$ git remote remove origin
$ git remote add origin <my origin>
$ git push -u -f origin main
```

I don't know if the `-u` flag contributed anything, but it doesn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the right remote origin url set ? By issuing `git remote show origin` are "Fetch URL" and "Push URL" set correctly according to your repository url ?

That was my mistake, I entered it manually and it was not the right path.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen when you are in a branch different than the one you think, let's call it "append". You need to return to main locally and push from there. But be careful, when you return to main, all your changes will be undone, and you will see only the code until the last edit of your local main.

Answer (score -1):

git commit -m "initial commit"

git push origin main

it worked for me

Answer (score -2):

Try `git add -A` instead of `git add .`

Answer (score -6):

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Don't know why so many bad votes, this is what worked for me git push origin master, git push origin alone pretend to work, but did not work, who knows if setting upstream or something would help too