# git push fails: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411

Tags: git, github

I have only one branch. For a few months I have been using

```
git push origin master
```

to commit to my local repository. Last night after I made some minor changes to my local repository and tried to push using the same command, I got this error:

```
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I googled and found questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/999907/1270459) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2936652/1270459), but none of the answers to these questions solves my problem.

Most of the answers suggest the problem of **detached head**. Yet I don't think my head is detached. Nor do I think I am on the wrong branch (as I only have one branch...)

I did a few experiments to figure out what's wrong, and here are the results I got:

(1) First comes my `git status` output

> ```
> # On branch master
> # Untracked files:
> #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
> #
> # egal.aux
> # egal.blg
> # egal.out
> # egal.pdf
> # egalcar.aux
> # egalcar.blg
> # egalcar.pdf
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
> ```

(2) When I type `git reflog`, I can see all my local commits, but the remote repository just won't get updated.

(3) When I type `git branch -a`, I get

> ```
> * master
>   remotes/origin/master
> ```

(4) When I type `git remote show origin`, I get

> ```
> * remote origin
>   Fetch URL: http://github.com/CherryQu921/egaldoc_en
>   Push  URL: http://github.com/CherryQu921/egaldoc_en
>   HEAD branch: master
>   Remote branch:
>     master tracked
>   Local ref configured for 'git push':
>     master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
> ```

I think the last line of output (the "fast-forwardable") is weird, but I am not sure what is wrong...

Comment: `fast-forwardable` means you can push your local changes to the remote branch, nothing criminal :-)

Answer (score 314, accepted):

If you attempt to push a large set of changes to a Git repository with HTTP or HTTPS, you may get an error message such as error: `RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411`. This is caused by a Git configuration default which limits certain HTTP operations to 1 megabyte.

To change this limit run within your local repository

```
git config http.postBuffer *bytes*
```

where bytes is the maximum number of bytes permitted. For example:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

For 500MB (thanks @Hengjie)

Comment: An example is `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` for 500MB.

Comment: If you are using gitlab, you may need to change your nginx config too (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab`). More info: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3099

Comment: what if it shows  ```RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 502```?

Comment: I am still getting following error git: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 504  in bitbucket on android studio

Answer (score 26):

You can also do this globally -

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

That will allow all local repos to push up to 500MB of data.

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions provided worked for us.  We had to switch to `ssh` to make this work instead of the `HTTPS` solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TortoiseGit for Windows, the easiest way is using the integrated configuration.

In a file explorer press left mouse button, select *TortoiseGit -> Settings*. Accept the info message. Now, you can choose if you want to configure the property only for the current project or system whide. For systemwide configuration press "edit systemwide gitconfig" and add the next line to the section `[http]`:

```
postBuffer = 524288000
```

(it the section `[http]` doesn't exist, create it)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the 22 error as follows:
In the "git clone" command I did NOT supply the user:password.
The clone worked, but not the push.
Solution for the 22 error:
Modify .git/config the url like this:
url=http://user:pwd@host/...
Then, the push worked.

Answer (score -1):

use `git lfs` and track files greater than 1 mb and then again try to push