# RPC failed; curl 18 Transferred a partial file: Laravel 11.x install error

Tags: laravel, git

everyone.
When I am trying to new laravel project, I got error:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

or

```
composer global require laravel/installer
 
laravel new example-app


##### error #####
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./remote-job"
    Installing laravel/laravel (v11.0.1)
    Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: E:\Xampp\php\php.ini
    Now trying to download from source
  - Syncing laravel/laravel (v11.0.1) into cache

In Git.php line 472:

  Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- https://ghp...RWI:x-oauth-basic@github.com/laravel/laravel.git "C:/Users/[user]/AppData/Local/Composer/vcs/https---github.com-laravel-laravel.git/"

  Cloning into bare repository 'C:/Users/[user]/AppData/Local/Composer/vcs/https---github.com-laravel-laravel.g
  it'...
  error: RPC failed; curl 18 Transferred a partial file
  error: 3200 bytes of body are still expected
  fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
  fatal: early EOF
  fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output




create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package> [<directory> [<version>]]]
```

So I tried with `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000` but it is same.

https://gist.github.com/enqtran/10e33674701967edd12c3cf224c835f8
https://github.com/ndmitchell/neil/issues/28

How can I fix this?

Comment: Dont ignore the first message "Installing laravel/laravel (v11.0.1) Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing" as for the RPC error, it's more complicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651749/git-push-fails-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-411

Comment: Not that much more complicated - it's usually a network timeout. How long did it take to get to that point?

Comment: It takes about 3-4 mins. But my internet is very good, I didn't resolve issue yet.

Comment: I fixed this issue. 
I forgot to set to env path both wampp and xampp.