# I can't push the main branch to Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I have tried many times to push my project to remote but I get this message:

```
Enumerating objects: 2694, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2694/2694), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2584/2584), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2694/2694), 55.98 MiB | 21.39 MiB/s, done.
Total 2694 (delta 519), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-12): A TLS fatal alert has been received.
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I have tried to find a solution on internet but I'm still stuck in this problem.

Comment: update your git

Comment: @WaqarHaider it is already updated

Comment: I think this might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651749/git-push-fails-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-411

Answer (score -1):

I was using Netgear wifi adapter and that prevented me from pushing to Gitlab. I used wired network cable and it worked.