# Git commit fails with "unable to auto-detect email address"

Tags: git, git-config

I'm going mad for this issue, I've installed git 2.8.4 and ConEmu on a fresh windows 10 machine, i can run most git command without any issue form command prompt.

I've set my user info with

git config --global user.name "My name"
git config --global user.mail mymail@mail.xx

but when i issue

git commit

all I can get is

---

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

### fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'xxxxx@xxxx.(none)')

I've checked the file in /Users/myaccount/.gitconfig and it's there with all required information, even worst if i issue

git config --global

it prints all the information from the file

The HOME variable is correctly set

I can't find where to knock my head...

Comment: `git config --global user.mail mymail@mail.xx` is it a typo? It should be 'user.email' instead of 'user.mail'

Comment: The OS version has nothing to do with the location of .gitconfig. It's the same for Windows 7, 8, 8.1, 10 etc. Try googling the error message. Eg [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671785/git-fatal-unable-to-auto-detect-email-address) faces the same problem on Ubuntu. One of the causes may be a spelling error. The same error is [explained in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662526/why-git-is-not-allowing-me-to-commit-even-after-configuration)

Comment: How come everyone misses the `e` in email? `user.mail` instead of `user.email`? This is a duplicate after all!

Comment: you are right i issued user.mail instead of user.email shouldn't you post as answer so i can assign it and close this item ?