# fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'M S@folder.(none)')

Tags: git-commit, git-config

i just not able to add file on github using git bash

error message :

```
fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'M S@folder.(none)')
```

i tried this command:

```
git commit -m "first commit" filename
```

any help ?

Comment: Run  `git config --global --list` . What does it return for `user.name` and `user.email`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git: fatal unable to auto-detect email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671785/git-fatal-unable-to-auto-detect-email-address)

Comment: error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/muradmohd01/TestGit.git'
 this message showing what to do??

Comment: looks like default branch is set to `main` or any other name and not `master`. Please verify if this is the case with you. message suggests refspec has no idea about master. please run `git show-ref` to see if it returns main or master

Answer (score 1):

When you installed git in your system first time, you have to set your user name and email. You can set your credentials using the below given command.

$ git config --global user.email "email_id"

$ git config --global user.name "user_name"