# Bizarre Git Error

Tags: git, github, version-control

So I get the

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'axmill@axmill-ThinkPad-T400.(none)')
```

error. But, I already entered my email and name.

EDIT: I was trying to make a commit, and it failed. But I had entered my email and name with the git config tool.

Git config output:

```
user.email=anchorfall551@gmail.com
user.name=Axmill
```

Comment: Did you run git config like it said?

Comment: What's triggering this error? What are you trying to do? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question

Comment: Please provide the output of `git config --global --get user.email` and `git config --global --get user.name`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the content of your global config and local config with:

```
git config --global -l
git config --local -l
```

You should see at least in one of those entries like:

```
user.name=VonC
user.email=vonc@laposte.net
```

(no quotes)

Make sure you are using the right commands (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14662703/6309))