# Git does not recognize user.name and user.mail (Windows 10)

Tags: git, windows-10

I have run into a weird situation with git in windows 10.

Although I have set my details using

```
git config --global user.name "My name"
git config --global user.email my@email.com
```

I keep getting this warning message whenever I try to commit:

```
Committer: "my_pc_username" <"my_pc_hostname">
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
```

The the commit author is indeed set with these details instead of the ones I set.

I have also run git config with `--system` as well as with no option switch just to be sure. Still the message persists.

I have also checked and both the `.gitconfig` file in `C:/Users/myuser` and the `config` file within the repo have the following section

```
[user]
    name = My Name
    mail = my@email.com
```

Finally, whenever I check with:

```
git config user.name
git config --global user.name
git config --system user.name
```

I get the right answer (`My Name`). Same for user.mail.

I am using git bash 2.7.3.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: open git bash and try it from there

Comment: What are you using to perform the `git` commands? (i.e. Git Bash, Git Cmd, Cmd, etc.)

Comment: Isn't the GIT_CONFIG env variable set to something? (echo $GIT_CONFIG)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Git is not allowing me to commit even after configuration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662526/why-git-is-not-allowing-me-to-commit-even-after-configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .gitconfig show a "mail" not "email" field, i think you like me falled in a duplicated of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662526/why-git-is-not-allowing-me-to-commit-even-after-configuration)

the right field is "email" perhaps you like me mistyped it when issued the command