# Can they help me with this error of Ionic? [ERROR] An error ocurred while running git commit -m "Initial commit" --no-gpg-sign (exit code 128)

Tags: git, github

I have this error, this error happens when I try to run this command

> ionic start myApp tabs

[image: ERROR 128]

Here is the error text:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript or ionic-framework. This is a git question. And the answer is in your screenshot. You have to run `git config` to set your name and email. See [config username](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/) and [config email](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git/) docs on GitHub.

Comment: great!, thank you very much styfle!

Comment: I added a more detailed answer. If that solves your problem, please click the checkmark to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command `git commit` will commit the changes into the git repository.

In order to make a commit, git needs to know your name and email address. After all, the purpose of a [SCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) tool is not just track the code changes but who made the changes!

The answer to your problem is in your screenshot.

- `git config --global user.name "My Name"` to set your name
- `git config --global user.email "email@example.com"` to set your email

See [config username](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/) and [config email](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git/) docs on GitHub or this related question:

[Why Git is not allowing me to commit even after configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14662526/266535)