# I want to push git easily

Tags: github

I want to push github without typing username and pass every time.

Using Ubuntu terminal, git asks me every time my user name and pass, when I pushing in MacOS, it did not happen.
I am setting correct global setting below.

```sh
git config --global user.name "username"  
git config --global user.email "my@email.com"
```

Saw this, ([Why Git is not allowing me to commit even after configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662526/why-git-is-not-allowing-me-to-commit-even-after-configuration))
and tried

```sh
git config --unset --local user.name
git config --unset --local user.email
```

but nothing happened.... Please help me.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/username/sh
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: `user.name` and `user.email` have nothing whatsoever to do with authentication. Those settings are just or authoring information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have setup your git repository using the `https` protocol:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/kaede0902/sh
```

The `https` protocol requires you to enter your username and password every time. You need to use the `ssh` protocol. For that, you need to create SSH keys first. I would recommend this guide: https://www.testingexcellence.com/install-git-mac-generate-ssh-keys/ . For your use case, when running `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, do not enter a passphrase.

Then, once that's done, either go to your local repository and execute the following command:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:kaede0902/sh.git
```

Or re-clone your repository somewhere else using the following command:

```
git clone git@github.com:kaede0902/sh.git
```

Comment: I remembered I made ssh key in the first PC! Thank you!!! But My blog reposity in Macbook, It seems to be being used https because ` url = https://github.com/kaede0902/blog` is written in /blog/.git/config

Comment: I could do this. used SSH. without pass and username

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up an SSH key for GitHub. See [How to connect to GitHub with SSH](https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)