# Merge branch to master with all changes?

Tags: git, merge

I sometimes find I'm working on a branch and I want to merge all changes from the branch into my master branch so that master is essential a clone of the branch I was just working with. Is there an easy way to update master so that all the changes from the branch are merged into the master. The behavior I am looking for is that master would become an exact clone of the branch. I usually merging individual conflicts one at a time into master, but is there an easier way to do this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks, this was precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reset --hard` with the id of the commit you want to be your new master head should be your solution.

http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html

EDIT : I'll flag it at duplicate : 
[How to replace master branch in git, entirely, from another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch)

Look at the solution in the duplicate I mention. But depending on the desired result, the reset I suggested may be the solution.

Comment: Keep in mind you'll lose all the commits you made in master that aren't also in the branch when you do this. (You can get back to them, but they won't be in a branch anymore.)

Comment: I thought this was the point.

Comment: Probably so. (I found the question a bit unclear; a "clone of the branch" would technically mean a separate copy.)

Comment: Clone was a poor choice of words. I was trying to indicate an exact version of the branch.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep history, use the `ours` merge strategy:

```
git checkout branch
git merge -s ours master
```

If you don't care about the history of your master branch, reset it:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard branch
```

(This will discard *all* your local changes and makes master's commit unreachable!)

If you don't have any commits in master that are not in your branch, you can fast-forward master to your branch:

```
git checkout branch
git merge master
# or `git merge --ff-only master` to only allow fast-forward
```

Comment: The last example will merge master into branch, rather than the other way around, will it not? And should that flag have been `--ff-only`?

Comment: @spinup: yes, `--ff-only`, thanks for pointing that out :) as for the direction of the merge, the OP asked "[so] that master would become an exact clone of the branch" which is what the commands do