# Need to merge a git branch forcefully onto the master after svn import

Tags: git, svn, git-merge, git-pull

I have a small project that was migrated from SVN.  I wasn't sure how to do it so I made a new git repo and two branches, 'master' and 'current'.  I then just copied the files into 'current' and continued development.

I finally got around to trying to import the changes to keep track of them.  I 'git svn fetch' the old repository and committed it to 'master'.  Now 'master' is a history of all the svn changes, and 'current' is my latest stuff.

I now want to just merge 'current' onto 'master', using 'current' as the absolute source of truth... so if it doesn't exist in 'current', it is deleted from 'master', and modified files in 'current' are used to overwrite the ones in 'master', all while keeping the commit history of 'current'.

Any ideas on the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redundant question

[How to replace master branch in git, entirely, from another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch)

> git checkout seotweaks
>
> git merge -s ours master
>
> git checkout master
>
> git merge seotweaks