# Git revert/cherry-pick to a commit beyond a merge

Tags: git, merge, revert, cherry-pick

This is my situation:

I am trying to place an **exact** copy of an earlier commit on top of my latest commit. However,

1. I have already pushed to remote, so do not want to simply `git reset
   --hard` (or, I would be happy to do so if I could somehow then add the earlier commit back on top of the latest commit)
2. in between my latest commit and the desired commit, I created and merged a branch, and this seems to give me problems/conflicts (otherwise would do a revert)
3. any solutions I have tried seem to retain additional changes from the other branch, which I do not want (I want my copy to look exactly like a checkout of the earlier commit)

I know this is probably a simple problem, but after much searching/trial and error I still cannot find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In case you're wondering why I want to do something like this, the original motivation was in order to easily use `git-latexdiff` to compare two versions separated by a merge.

### To reproduce this scenario/see an example:

In order to make this scenario reproducible, the commands below will make a folder called `tryrevert` with the necessary structure:

```
mkdir tryrevert; cd tryrevert; git init; echo 'line 1 commit 1' > file1.txt; git add .; git commit -m 'commit 1'; echo 'line 2 commit 2 only want these two lines' >> file1.txt; git add .; git commit -m 'commit 2 - WANT THIS ONE'; git branch sidebranch; git checkout sidebranch; echo 'another file - only in sidebranch' > sidefile.txt; git add .; git commit -m 'commit 3 - sidebranch work'; git checkout master; echo 'extra work' >> file1.txt; git add .; git commit -m 'commit 4 - some more work on master'; git merge sidebranch -m 'commit 5 - the merge'; echo 'final work after the merge' >> file1.txt; git add .; git commit -m 'commit 6 - latest commit '
git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline
```

and will output the following commit tree (excluding `origin/master`):

```
* 7c4c7a1 (HEAD, origin/master, master) commit 6 - latest commit
*   5b0077c commit 5 - the merge
|\
| * 20a1164 (sidebranch) commit 3 - sidebranch work
* | 3a5a24f commit 4 - some more work on master
|/
* 925228b commit 2 - WANT THIS ONE
* 52af39e commit 1
```

(I left `sidebranch` where it is rather than moving it up to `master` for clarity.)

So **what I want is**:

```
* abcdefg (HEAD, master) COPY OF commit 6 
* hijklmn COPY OF commit 2
* 7c4c7a1 (origin/master) commit 6 - latest commit
*   5b0077c commit 5 - the merge
|\
| * 20a1164 (sidebranch) commit 3 - sidebranch work
* | 3a5a24f commit 4 - some more work on master
|/
* 925228b commit 2 - WANT THIS ONE
* 52af39e commit 1
```

Notes:

i) `sidebranch` creates `sidefile.txt`, and all efforts I have at reverting to **commit 2** end up containing `sidefile.txt` (and I do not want **COPY of commit 2** to contain `sidefile.txt`). I would also like to avoid having to deal with merge conflicts in `file1.txt`.

ii) I've tried `rebase -i` and `cherry-pick`, but without success (perhaps I am doing it incorrectly) - I keep running into conflicts.

iii)  If I did not have the merge, something like:

```
git revert --no-commit master...HEAD~3; git add .; git commit -m 'reverting to commit 2'
```

would work for me, but the merge seems stop this exact line from working.

iv) I have spent time looking at many posts on stackoverflow, but couldn't find one that dealt with this specific scenario...

### Edit:

(apologies in advance for the long edit, but want to clarify the state of the two commits)

In response to @Juan's question, and to make it clear, commit 6 contains

`file1.txt`:

> line 1 commit 1
>   line 2 commit 2 only want these two lines
>   extra work
>   final work after the merge

`sidefile.txt`

> another file - only in sidebranch

On the other hand, in commit 2 `file1.txt` contains only the first two lines:

> line 1 commit 1
>   line 2 commit 2 only want these two lines

**and there is no** `sidefile.txt` in commit 2.

@Juan's answer below works well for reverting/cherry-picking `file1.txt`, but the created commit still contains `sidefile.txt` (which I don't want).

After playing around with "theirs", "ours" and other flags, [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch/2862938#2862938) provided a solution:

```
git checkout master~1^1~1
git checkout -b commit2branch
git merge -s ours master -m 'revert to commit2'
git checkout master
git merge commit2branch
git branch -D commit2branch
```

which works, in terms of getting the files to be in the correct state (correct `file1.txt`, no `sidefile.txt` but then the commit history contains an extra branch:

```
*   4236c61 (HEAD, master) revert to commit2
|\
| * 7c4c7a1 (origin/master) commit 6 - latest commit
| *   5b0077c commit 5 - the merge
| |\
| | * 20a1164 commit 3 - sidebranch work
| |/
|/|
| * 3a5a24f commit 4 - some more work on master
|/
* 925228b commit 2 - WANT THIS ONE
* 52af39e commit 1
```

while I do not want this extra branch...

### Final edit

I have an answer, which I have posted below, and is based on @Juan's second solution. However, the solution uses several reverts, while **I would really like a one-line solution**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I ran your script to generate the repo, I will post it here and use my commits in the answer to avoid copy/paste/change errors:

```
* f2cb927 (HEAD, master) commit 6 - latest commit
*   93e6ede commit 5 - the merge
|\  
| * 61f0cfe (sidebranch) commit 3 - sidebranch work
* | c1d2916 commit 4 - some more work on master
|/  
* 79570e8 commit 2 - WANT THIS ONE
* 5e7f2fb commit 1
```

Then there are different possibilities:
**First:** to end up with your second graph, you could do it with two cherry-picks, first of commit 2, then of commit 6. This will have conflicts and as you are taking a commit contained in the same branch history you would probably want to use their changes in case of conflict, so assuming that you are checked out in `master` you would probably want to do this:

```
$ git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X theirs 79570e8
```

and afterwards the same for commit 6:

```
$ git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X theirs f2cb927
```

With this you would end up with a graph as you want:

```
* f6e3ff7 (HEAD, master) commit 6 - latest commit
* 7563975 commit 2 - WANT THIS ONE
* f2cb927 commit 6 - latest commit
*   93e6ede commit 5 - the merge
|\  
| * 61f0cfe (sidebranch) commit 3 - sidebranch work
* | c1d2916 commit 4 - some more work on master
|/  
* 79570e8 commit 2 - WANT THIS ONE
* 5e7f2fb commit 1
```

But I understand correctly this is not what you want, as the repo would contain File1:

> line 1 commit 1
>   line 2 commit 2 only want these two lines
>   extra work
>   final work after the merge

And File2:

> another file - only in sidebranch

Git will take into account every single commit contained in the branch, giving preference to newer commits, but a cherry-pick will not 'undo' commits from the branch, for that purpose you would need to use revert.
**Second possibility:** This is complex as requires somehow dealing with conflicts and this can be messy when reverting things. Well, I created a new branch called 'new' in commit 5:

```
$ git checkout 93e6ede
$ git branch new
$ git checkout new
```

and from it I ran:

```
$ git revert c1d2916
$ git revert 61f0cfe
$ git revert -m 1 93e6ede
```

And I ended up with the following tree (note **new** branch):

```
* 9eeac5c (HEAD, new) Revert "commit 3 - sidebranch work"
* e1f3678 Revert "commit 4 - some more work on master"
| * f6e3ff7 (master) commit 6 - latest commit
| * 7563975 commit 2 - WANT THIS ONE
| * f2cb927 commit 6 - latest commit
|/  
*   93e6ede commit 5 - the merge
|\  
| * 61f0cfe (sidebranch) commit 3 - sidebranch work
* | c1d2916 commit 4 - some more work on master
|/  
* 79570e8 commit 2 - WANT THIS ONE
* 5e7f2fb commit 1
```

Having in 'new' only File1:

> line 1 commit 1
>   line 2 commit 2 only want these two lines
>   Then, if you want commit 6 as well without having to modify the history, you would need to add your work after commit 6 now that you can deal with conflicts properly, which is the last one:

```
$ git rebase f2cb927
```

Here there is no other solution than dealing with the conflicts and manually selecting what you want.

**Third possibility and probably best** seen how messy the second is: With a different branch (to see the changes), say new2, checkout in commit 2. Then simply do:

```
$ git cherry-pick f2cb927
```

Here you might have conflicts but they should be quite straight forward to solve, as all you want in the actual content of commit 6. Once conflicts are solved:

```
$ git add files
$ git cherry-pick --continue
```

Then your final tree with all three possibilities would look like this:

```
* 2ded558 (HEAD, new2) commit 6 - latest commit
| * ec8ef14 (new) Revert "commit 3 - sidebranch work"
| * 9f8bb91 Revert "commit 4 - some more work on master"
| | * f6e3ff7 (master) commit 6 - latest commit
| | * 7563975 commit 2 - WANT THIS ONE
| |/  
| * f2cb927 commit 6 - latest commit
| *   93e6ede commit 5 - the merge
| |\  
| | * 61f0cfe (sidebranch) commit 3 - sidebranch work
| |/  
|/|   
| * c1d2916 commit 4 - some more work on master
|/  
* 79570e8 commit 2 - WANT THIS ONE
* 5e7f2fb commit 1
```

Just go for your preferred option, you obviously don't need the three of them. Assuming that you want you would need to force the push git push --force origin branchName. Doing this whatever else was in remote before would be lost and replaced by the new data on the push.

Comment: Dear @Juan - thanks for your detailed reply. Your answer is close to what I want. What I want is for the (reverted) repo "commit 2" to **only** have `file1.txt` containing only the two lines  `line 1 commit 1
line 2 \n commit 2 only want these two lines` (and **no** `sidefile.txt`). In other words, the exact same "snapshot" as if you had used `git checkout 79570e8` (using your commit ID for `commit 2`). Your `cherry-pick --strategy=recursive` has the correct `file1.txt`, but still contains `sidefile.txt` (which I do not want).

Comment: Hi dean, please check the modifications on the post, I guess the easiest would be the third option if you can force a push.

Comment: Thank you **very much** for your response.  
Your third solution is good if I would be prepared to deal with conflicts, but I am trying to find a way to avoid having to manually handle any conflicts.  
However, your **second solution** is the closest to what I want. I have rewritten it in a post below. I just wish there were a simpler way to do this/a way to do this in one line.  
I have upvoted your post, but don't have the necessary reputation points for it to appear...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Juan - **his second solution** could be rewritten as:

```
git checkout master
git revert --no-commit HEAD...HEAD~1
git revert --no-commit -m 1 HEAD~1
git revert --no-commit --strategy=recursive -X theirs HEAD~1^1
git commit -m 'COPY of commit 2 using revert'
```

and with:

```
git revert --no-commit HEAD
git commit -m 'COPY of commit 6 using revert'
```

this would produce the desired commit tree:

```
* a30d0b1 (HEAD, master) COPY of commit 6 using revert
* bcbd36f COPY of commit 2 using revert
* 7c4c7a1 (origin/master) commit 6 - latest commit
*   5b0077c commit 5 - the merge
|\
| * 20a1164 commit 3 - sidebranch work
* | 3a5a24f commit 4 - some more work on master
|/
* 925228b commit 2 - WANT THIS ONE
* 52af39e commit 1
```

but, **I wish there were a way to do this in one line...**