# Error on git merge -s ours - "untracked working tree files"

Tags: git, merge

I'm migrating to Laravel 5 from Laravel 4.2.   To do this I've cloned my master branch and made all of my changes in a new feature branch.

I'm now finished with the migration and ready to replace the contents of my master branch with the contents of my new feature branch.   I'm pretty weak on git, but I found this SO answer that looks really straightforward:  [How to replace master branch in git, entirely, from another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch)  - here is the short version:

```
git checkout seotweaks
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge seotweaks
```

When I get to the third step and try to checkout the master branch, I get the following error:

```
The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
```

with a list of every file in my `app/models` folder.   I don't have any local changes that haven't been committed and pushed to the new feature branch.

I did move that folder as part of the migration, but I can see the referenced files in the source on the new feature branch on bitbucket.

Does anyone see a step I'm missing or know of a different approach that I could take to get this working?

Edit:

`git checkout FTW` - works fine

`git merge -s ours master` - works fine

`git checkout master fails` - please see error below.

Results from git checkout master:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Development/memberSherpa$ git checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by      checkout:

app/models/Authors.php
app/models/BusinessAct.php
app/models/Contractor.php
app/models/Customer.php
app/models/Dues.php
app/models/Email.php
app/models/Groups.php
app/models/Skill.php
app/models/Txt.php
app/models/User.php
app/models/UserGroup.php

Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

results from git status:

```
On branch FTW
Your branch is up-to-date with 'username/FTW'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Edit 2:

Here is a screen shot from SourceTree that show my commits while upgrading to L5.

I had to make some changes to an API on the master after FTW branch was created (9 commits). Those changes were added to FTW earlier today. I've highlighted the commit that moved the models.

[image: sourceTree]

Comment: What is the output of `git status --ignored`?

Comment: --ignored returns some test uploads, logs and views: storage/framework/views/f652ea5b02e7724ebc3f79ade54848fc  It doesn't contain any files from app/models though

Comment: Does `.gitignore` differ between the two branches? I'd post the contents of it so we can be absolutely sure there aren't any syntactical errors.

Comment: I just ran both git ignores through a diff checker.  They are the same, except  FTW has  app/storage/*  and master has app/storage/uploads/*

Answer (score 0):

git doesn't know these local changes are the same as what already exist in the repo since the local changes are untracked on your current branch. You need to either commit them or reset to a clean commit before merging.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand.   I moved the folder but I then committed/pushed those changes to the new branch.  I don't have any local files that need committing.   Is there a reason they would be listed as untracked changes?  Should I git add .  ?

Comment: Use `git status` to see which files git is complaining about.

Comment: git status: On branch FTW
Your branch is up-to-date with 'username/FTW'. nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: What happens now when you do the merge? If you still have problems, please edit your question to include the results of `git status` when a particular step fails.

Comment: I updated the question with the errors I am receiving.  Thanks

Comment: Check your `.gitignore` file(s). I'm willing to bet that these files or a directory somewhere in the path are all being ignored in the current commit.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't it.  I double checked .gitignore and then edited one of the files. The edited file appears when I run git status.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm stumped. I apologize for assuming this was a noob git question.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am a git noob for sure.