# Git replace master branch with another branch - git merge -s ours?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I am fairly new to Git, having only been using it for the last few months, since taking on a new client (it was what they had been using to manage version control of their software before I started working for them).

I recently merged a `development` branch with my local `master` branch, and pushed `master` to the server. I had tested the site (website written in Django/ Python) on my local development machine prior to pushing it to the server, and it all appeared to be working correctly (including the bug fix that had been implemented on the `development` branch).

However, after testing the changes that had been made after pushing to the server, I found that something had broken a part of the site. So I checked out an old `commit` on the server, and the live version is now using that old `commit`, meaning that it is in a 'Detached HEAD' state, but is functional.

So, my local `master` branch is currently the version with the bug fix that I had pushed to the server (which is working locally, but didn't on the server), but since I need to work on another aspect of the site, I want to revert to a backup of `master` that I had made prior to merging the `development` branch with the bug fix into `master`, so that I am developing from the 'most recent working' state of the code.

The branches I have on my machine are:

`master` (with `development` merged into it, which has broken something else)

`masterBackup` (i.e. the `master` branch as it was before merging `development` into it)

`development` (which is the branch on which the original bug has been fixed, but something else is now broken)

So effectively, `masterBackup` is actually my working 'master' branch at the moment, since merging `development` into `master` broke `master`. I want to make `masterBackup` my 'master' branch again, and `master` in its current state can be discarded/ removed. I still have the `development` branch, so can look into why/ how this broke the site and fix it there before merging it to `master` again.

I found the question at [How to replace master branch in git, entirely, from another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch) on which the accepted answer indicates that I should do the following steps:

```
git checkout masterBackup
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge masterBackup
```

But I can't find anything definitive explaining what the command `git merge -s ours` does... is this definitely how to make my `masterBackup` branch the `master` branch again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commands in that post is not suitable for you. The result of the commands is make the masterBackup branch contains all the changes in master branch. Of cause this is not what you want.

If you just want masterBackup branch work as master branch, you can rename it by

```
git branch -m master master1
git branch -m masterBackup master
```

Now the masterBackup is replace master branch. But if you want to push local master branch to remote master, you should use `git push -f origin master`.

Answer (score 1):

The safest option is to revert the commits which were made to your `master` branch happening *after* the detached commit where everything is working properly:

```
git revert <SHA-1>^..HEAD   # SHA-1 is the earliest commit you want gone
```

This option will make a commit on top of `master` which undoes each of the commits in the range.  After this, your branch should be functionally identical to where you want it.  You can continue working as usual and push as usual.

But you could also rewrite the history of `master` if you wanted to.

Warning: This option will rewrite the history of your published `master` branch and therefore should only be considered if you can handle the caveats that come with this.

If you want to permanently revert your `master` branch to an earlier commit you can do the following steps:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <SHA-1 of earlier commit you want to keep>
```

This will overwrite your local `master` branch such that its HEAD is now the earlier functioning commit.

Note that this will change the history of the remote published `master` branch, so in order to update the remote, you will have to do a force push via:

```
git push --force origin master
```