# Reversing a git merge with ours strategy

Tags: git, git-merge

I followed one of the answers in [How to replace master branch in git, entirely, from another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch) with the following commands:

```
git checkout seotweaks
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge seotweaks
```

Then I pushed the changes to the remote repository.
Unfortunately these changes erased EVERYTHING on the old MASTER which was entirely replaced by the seotweaks branch including the history itself.
Is there a way to undo this and go back to the old MASTER?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is *erased* here, certainly not yet.  Adding a commit only ever *adds* to the repository.  Everything you had before, you *still have*.

Remember what a commit *is*: it's a complete snapshot of a source tree, along with some additional information: who made the commit and when, a log message, and the identity of some *parent* commit.  Each commit has its own unique name, which is one of those big ugly hash IDs like `e0688e9b28f2c5ff711460ee8b62077be5df2360`.  If we give this hash ID to Git, Git can retrieve that commit, including its complete-snapshot-of-files exactly as they were when we *saved* the snapshot.

Branch *names* like `master` and `seotweaks` are merely human-readable names that correspond to these big ugly hash IDs.  Each name stores one (and *only* one) such ID.  Whenever you make a *new* commit, whether it is by running `git commit` or `git merge`, you tell Git to:

- store a new snapshot (we'll worry about where the new snapshot itself comes from later)
- using your name as the author and committer
- and a log message
- and which remembers the *previous* commit (by hash ID) as its *parent*, or, for a merge commit, as the first of *two* parents.

The new commit gets its own new (and unique) hash ID, and Git then stores the *new* ID in the branch name.

Hence, the files as they were in `master` *before* you did any of this are *still in the repository*.  They're just no longer found by the name `master`.  You need to find—or tell Git to find—the original hash ID, the one `master` had back when you liked the associated snapshot.

#### How ordinary commits work

For ordinary, non-merge commits, this process is pretty straightforward.  Consider a repository with just three commits.  Instead of the big ugly hash IDs, I will use one-letter names for them, and call the current (third) commit `C`.  The name `master` stores the ID for `C`, so we say that `master` *points to* `C`.  Commit `C` itself stores the ID for earlier commit `B`, so we say that `C` *points to* `B`:

```
<--B  <--C   <--master
```

Note how these "points-to"s are attached to the commits themselves, so that once we have found `C`, we can use `C` to *find* `B`.  But how do we find `C`?  One way would be to memorize `e0688e9b28f2c5ff711460ee8b62077be5df2360` or whatever, but that's a terrible way.  Instead, we use the *name*, `master`, to remember `e0688e9b28f2c5ff711460ee8b62077be5df2360` for us.

`B`, of course, points to `A`.  But `A` was the very first commit we ever made: where does it point?  It's supposed to point to the earlier commit; but there *is no* earlier commit.  So the answer is, it doesn't point anywhere.  We call this a *root commit*.  If we draw `A` in we have the final, complete picture of the repository's commits:

```
A <--B  <--C   <--master
```

Note again how everything works backwards in Git: we start with the *most recent* commit, which we find by a branch name like `master`.  That commit finds an earlier *parent* commit, which finds another parent, and so on.  This process stops only when we hit the root commit, which has no parent (though of course we can get tired and just stop looking :-) whenever we want).

To add a *new* commit `D` to the repository, Git:

1. writes out a source-tree snapshot;
2. writes a commit with you as author and committer, "now" as the time of the commit, and your log message as the log message; and this new commit *points to* the current commit `C`;
3. takes the new hash ID for the new `D` and stuffs *that* into the name `master`.

Note that the only thing that ever *changes* here is the *name*.  The new commit, `D`, is *new*.  It's not changed, it's *new*.  `C` is still exactly as it was before, sitting there pointing to `B`.  `B` is also unchanged, as is `A`.  Let's draw this new result:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

There's no need for the internal arrows: we know that (1) they all point "backwards", and (2) they *never change*.  `D`'s parent is now `C`, and will be forever; `C`'s parent is still `B`; and so on.

This is a way to draw *commit graphs*, i.e., pictures of what commits find what other commits, and how we find the most recent commits in the first place.  **You need to learn to draw and view commit graphs, to use Git properly.**

#### How merge commits work

This is how commits work—but it's also how *merge* commits work, just with a tweak.  A *merge* commit has two parents.<sup>1</sup>  That is, it "points back" to *two* earlier commits.  Let's draw just *part* of a more interesting commit graph, with two branches:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
      \
       J---K---L   <-- sidebr
```

The way we *got* this graph was, clearly, that we made a bunch of commits on `master`, so that the name `master` now points to commit `L`.  At some point, we did a `git checkout -b sidebr` or something along those lines, so that `sidebr` pointed to commit `F`; but then we made a new commit `J` on it, so `J` now points back to `F`.  Then we made `K` and `L` on `sidebr`, so that the *name* `sidebr` points to `L`.  `L` points to `K`, which points to `J`, which points to `F`; `master` points to `I`, which points to `H`, which points to `G`, which points to `F`.

(Note that we never changed `F`.  This is one of the reasons Git's internal arrows are all backwards: we don't know, when we first make `F`, how many *children* it will have in the future.  But when we bring forth a new child like `G` or `J`, we know it has one *parent*, which is `F`.)

Now, let's say you `git checkout master && git merge sidebr` to make a new *merge commit* on `master`.

The merge process somehow—we'll see more on this in just a moment—*combines* the two source-tree snapshots for `I` and `L`, so that we can have a new snapshot for our new *merge commit* `M`.  Then it saves that snapshot and makes the new commit as usual.  But instead of just pointing back to `I`, the new *merge commit* points back to *both* old commits:

```
...--F--G--H--I--M   <-- master (HEAD)
      \         /
       J---K---L   <-- sidebr
```

and now Git changes the name `master` so that it points to `M`.  (The name `sidebr` stays the same here.)  I put the word `(HEAD)` in this time to show which branch is the one we have checked out, since with two branch-names in the diagram, it's no longer obvious.

Incidentally, the term for the commit to which some branch name points, like `M` or `L` here, is that it is the *tip* commit of that branch.  `M` is the new tip of `master`, and `L` is the tip of `sidebr`.

There's another twist to `git merge`, which we will get to in a moment, but for now let's just mention that `git merge` sometimes—when it can, and when you let it—doesn't actually bother making a new merge commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>A merge commit is any commit with two *or more* parents, technically.  But we do not need to worry about the "or more" case.

---

#### Now, let's draw what you did with your first merge

You had two branches named `master` and `seotweaks` and you ran:

```
git checkout seotweaks
git merge -s ours master
```

The `git checkout` command set `HEAD` to `seotweaks` (and retrieved the `seotweak` tip commit's snapshot from the repository, putting that into the *index* and *work-tree*).  The `git merge` then *combined* the current commit's tree with that of `master`, and now it's time to talk about the "somehow" part of how `git merge` combines snapshots.

The `-s ours` is what Git calls a *merge strategy*.  A merge strategy is just "instructions for how to combine snapshots".  The `ours` strategy is the simplest one of all: it says "ignore the other snapshot, just use ours."

In other words, we completely throw away the other commit's work, and just use our own snapshot.  "We" are the tip commit of `seotweaks`:

```
...--P--Q   <-- seotweaks (HEAD)

...--S--T   <-- master
```

so we *keep* our source tree snapshot, but make a new merge commit `U`.  For no really obvious reason, I'm going to draw `U` on a line by itself here.  `U` points back to both `Q` and `T`, of course, just as before:

```
...--P--Q
         \
          U   <-- seotweaks (HEAD)
         /
...--S--T   <-- master
```

The *source tree snapshot* for commit `U` is exactly the same as the snapshot for commit `Q`.  But the two are different *commits:* they have different big ugly hash IDs.  The new commit's hash ID is now in `seotweaks`.

Now we get to your second merge, for which you ran:

```
git checkout master
git merge seotweaks
```

The first step, `git checkout master`, swapped out our index and work-tree and current commit from `U` to `T`.  There is no change at all to the *graph*, we just move `HEAD`:

```
...--P--Q
         \
          U   <-- seotweaks
         /
...--S--T   <-- master (HEAD)
```

The second step, though ... well, look at `seotweaks`: it's *already merged* with `master`.  Instead of making a new *merge commit*, Git can just "slide the label `master` forward" along the backwards arrow going from `U` to `T`.

Git calls this a *fast forward merge*, although it's not actually a merge at all.  What Git does is, in effect, to check out commit `U` and move the *name* `master` to point to `U`:

```
...--P--Q
         \
          U   <-- master (HEAD), seotweaks
         /
...--S--T
```

We now have two *branch names* for the same *tip commit* `U`.  That's quite an ordinary thing to have in Git, and it's one of the many reasons that you need to get good at drawing and interpreting *commit graphs*.

#### A side note about `git log`

When you run `git log`, Git:

1. looks up `HEAD` to find your current branch;
2. uses that branch's *tip* commit to show you the first commit it shows you;
3. uses that commit to find its parent or parents;
4. shows you one of the parents just as in step 2;
5. repeats forever, showing you all of the parents, in some order.

When `HEAD` names `master` which names commit `U`, `git log` first shows you the merge commit, then shows you one of its parent commits, i.e., `Q` or `T`.  Let's say it picks `T`.  Which commit does it show *next*?  Should it show `Q` now?  Or should it show `S` now?

This is a trick question: the right answer is that there's no right answer. :-)  What `git log` normally does is to partly sort by commit time stamps, and partly follow other rules.  It gives you flags such as `--author-date` or `--topo-sort` to *force* it to use some particular order.  It also gives you `--graph`, which tells it to draw a commit graph (vertically, with newer commits towards the top and older ones towards the bottom, rather than horizontally like I have here), and using `--graph` turns on `--topo-order` and hence changes the displayed order.

There's never a perfectly right order here because you have to look up both "legs" of the merge at the *same time* (in parallel), but `git log` has to show you one *commit* at a time, serially.  This is yet another reason to get used to drawing and reading commit graphs.  As a mnemonic, remember to get help from A DOG: use `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`.  (Some might prefer to use "a god", "all graph oneline decorate".  Just remember the dyslexic agnostic, who is not sure whether to believe in Dog.)

#### How to undo your merge

Now, there are two ways to "undo" a merge.  One is a sort of potentially-destructive process, using `git branch -f` or `git reset --hard`.  In this particular case, it doesn't actually destroy anything, which makes this example complicated.  To make the example itself less complicated, let's imagine that we somehow first make `seotweaks` itself move back to point to commit `Q` (and in fact, this is easy to do, using `git branch -f seotweaks seoweaks~1`):

```
...--P--Q   <-- seotweaks
         \
          U   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--S--T
```

We are still on `master` (HEAD = master) and `master` still points to commit `U`.  If we first find the raw hash ID for commmit `T`, and then run:

```
git reset --hard <that-big-ugly-hash-ID>
```

this will make Git, in effect, check out commit `T` *and* move the branch name `master` to *point to* `T` again, giving:

```
...--P--Q   <-- seotweaks
         \
          U     [abandoned]
         /
...--S--T   <-- master (HEAD)
```

What happens to commit `U`?  The answer is in the graph drawing above: we no longer have any *names* for it, because `seotweaks` names `Q` and `master` names `T`.  Commit `U` is therefore abandoned: thrown to the wolves.  Eventually (but not until at least 30 days later, by default), Git will really throw it away.  Until then, `git log` won't normally show it, because `git log` starts at `HEAD`—or with `--all`, starts at *all* branch-tip commits—and works backwards from there.  Starting from `Q` and `T`, we will never *find* `U`.

Now, that's how to *throw out* the commit entirely.  If we do that *without* first modifying the name `seotweaks`, the graph looks like this instead:

```
...--P--Q
         \
          U   <-- seotweaks
         /
...--S--T   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and commit `U` sticks around, because it has a name by which we can find it.  Using `git log` from `seotweaks` shows us `U`, and then `Q` or `T` first, and then more commits eventually including whichever one of `Q` or `T` it did not show earlier.  If you want to keep `U` but force `master` back one step so that it *forgets* `U`, this is how to do it.

(Note that you need to find the hash ID of `T`.  There is a fast way, but I will leave that for another answer.)

#### Push and force-push

When you `git push`, you are connecting *your* Git, with your repository, to another Git, which has its own, separate repository.  You tell *your* Git to call up this other Git, often over the Internet-phone.  You then have your Git give, to the other Git, any *new* commits you have made, and then have your Git ask *their* Git to change some of *their* branch names.

If you add a new commit `U` and `git push` the result, your Git calls up their Git.  Let's say that their Git has the *same* `seotweaks` and `master` that you had before all this merging.  In other words, they have this graph:

```
...--P--Q   <-- seotweaks

...--S--T   <-- master
```

(there's no need for `HEAD` here as we are not using their *current* commit in any way; we are just asking them to change some of their branch names).  We give them new commit `U`, which has the hash IDs of `Q` and `T` in it.  They already have those commits `Q` and `T` (by hash ID) so our Git does not have to hand those over, only `U` itself (by hash ID!).

Then, our Git asks their Git to move *their* `master`—and maybe also their `seotweaks`, depending on what *we* tell *our* Git to ask of them, but let's suppose we only ask them to change their `master`—so that their `master` points to commit `U`:

```
...--P--Q   <-- seotweaks
         \
          U   <-- master
         /
...--S--T
```

They now have the merge commit (by hash ID) and their `master` now *remembers* it (by hash ID).

If we `git reset --hard` our own `master` so that it points back to `T`, and run `git push origin master` again, we'll have our Git call up their Git again.  Our Git will give them no commits—we have nothing *new*—and then ask them to set their `master` to point to commit `T` (again, by its big ugly hash ID).

But they will say *no!*

If they were to change their `master` to point back to `T`, that would abandon, in their repository, their commit `U`.  They don't know—they don't *remember*—that we gave them `U`; all they know and care about is that this would *remove* `U` from `master`.

We can turn our polite request, "move your `master`", into a command: "move your `master` now, or else!"  We do this with `--force` or `-f`.  It's still up to them whether to *obey* the command, but if they do, they will lose their `U`.

That *might* be what we want.  But what if someone else, with access to that other Git, has added on a *new* commit `V`:

```
...--P--Q   <-- seotweaks
         \
          U--V   <-- master
         /
...--S--T
```

We now command them: "set your `master` to `T`!"  If they obey, this is the result:

```
...--P--Q   <-- seotweaks
         \
          U--V [abandoned]
         /
...--S--T   <-- master
```

We have not only wiped out our `U` commit, but also that `V` commit someone *else* added.  So this is the first danger of a force-push.

Another is that someone else—some *third* person with her own Git and her own repository—may have picked up this commit `U`.  Even if you convince your other (second) Git to forget commit `U`, she—the third person with the third Git—can now *re-introduce* `U`.  This is the second danger of a force-push.

The way to handle both of these is to *communicate with your team* about any force-pushes.  Make sure they all know that you are going to do this, that they all agree that it is *safe* to do so; then do it; then let them all know that it is now done, and they can go back to work as normal.

#### There is another alternative

We don't *have* to *remove* our mistake.  We added this new commit `U`, but now we decide: *Oh, that's bad!  We want the snapshot commit at the tip of `master` to match the snapshot in commit `T`.*  Instead of trying to *remove* commit `U`, we can add our own new commit `V`:

```
...--P--Q
         \
          U   <-- seotweaks
         / \
...--S--T   V   <-- master (HEAD)
```

This graph is, obviously, more complicated—but it has the advantage that we're only *adding new commits*, not trying to rewind history in some way and discard existing commits.

It's a little tricky to make a new `master` commit whose saved snapshot exactly matches that for `T`, but only a little: there are a bunch of ways that will do it.  The most straightforward (albeit inefficient) is to combine `git rm -r -- .` with a subsequent `git checkout <hash> -- .`, and then to commit, while on `master` and in the top level directory of the repository.  The `git rm` removes everything from index and work-tree, then the `git checkout` re-fills everything from the specified hash.

(You can also *revert* a merge, which is pretty similar.)

Whether you *should* do this depends on how good you feel about trying to remove/abandon the merge commit.  Can you communicate with the rest of your team?  Will they understand all of this?  If so, removing the bad merge entirely (by force pushing after reset) is pretty nice: it leaves the graph uncluttered, there are no land mines waiting for a *future* merge (leaving a bad merge in, with or without a revert of that merge, can make the *next* merge more difficult).  If not, you may have to use the history-preserving, but more-painful, method of backing out the merge manually.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `git log`, if you see the last commit before all this happend, you can do this command :

```
git reset --hard origin/{commit-id}
git push
```

Comment: I guess, after doing `hard reset` force push is needed, *git push -f origin master*

Comment: Be careful with force push (this is advice to everyone, but especially to Renato, the original question-asker). Force push *can* really erase things. Ordinary commits and merges, though, *never* "erase" *anything*.

Comment: as the guys mentioned, be careful with that