# Git replace master branch with unrelated history

Tags: git, github, merge

I have two branches in my repository: master and devel. I tried to merge devel into master but got the error `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`.

On github, the master branch contains some files that I do not care about and do not need to merge. I do not need to keep the history of the master branch, I simply want to replace master with what is on devel.

Once I get devel updated to master, I need to tell my partner how to pull master without merging into his old local copy of master.

What I am considering doing is using advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch) post and running:

```
git branch -m master old-master
git branch -m devel master
git push -f origin master
git branch -d old-master
```

Do you think this will work? What should I tell my partner in order for him to get the latest copy of master once this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got into quite a messy situation here.
Assuming your branch replacement went well you need to ask your partner if he have changes he would like to commit no his side.

- If no changes on his side I would recommend cloning the remote repository and
  starting from fresh.
- If your partner has changes I would recommend making a copy of the locale branch and cherry picking the changes.

Partner:

```
git checkout –b master_tmp master
git checkout master_tmp
git branch –D master
git fecth
git checkout master
#Locate the changes you are missing 
git log  master_tmp
git cherry pick sha1x…sha1y # look at the documentation of cherry pick.
#Resolve conflicts as usual  
git commit 
git push
```

Comment: The branch replacement went well. My partner does not have commits from his side. What is wrong with him doing git fetch, then git reset --hard origin/master?

Comment: You can try it but why not play it safe and avoid some later unexpected voodoo. you can just delete master with -D and checkout if you prefer not to clone.

Comment: so run git branch -D master, then git fetch, git checkout master?

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior has changed since git 2.9:

> "git merge" used to allow merging two branches that have no common
> base by default, which led to a brand new history of an existing
> project created and then get pulled by an unsuspecting maintainer,
> which allowed an unnecessary parallel history merged into the existing
> project. The command has been taught not to allow this by default,
> with an escape hatch --allow-unrelated-histories option to be used in
> a rare event that merges histories of two projects that started their
> lives independently.

See the [git release changelog](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt#L58-L68) for more information.

You can use `--allow-unrelated-histories` to force the merge to happen.

**Example:** `git pull origin branchname --allow-unrelated-histories`