# GIT commit in two different source branches

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have 2 branches: *develop* & *master*. *Master* is always behind *develop*. Now I created a new branch called *new-branch*, which is essentially *develop* but has different source hierarchy (for example, Java package naming was totally changed), but functionality/logic remains the same. Then I would like to continue development in both branches for a while. What I usually do - push commit into *develop* and then cherry-pick it to *new-branch*, and fix any possible conflicts.

**Question1**: Is there any better way to do this if I really need to keep both branches? Merging/rebasing seems to not work here because it merges entire source tree.

Now after a while I decided that *develop* branch could be replaced by *new-branch*. And later on master should also contain same changes. What I usually do - just delete *develop* & *master* and rename *new-branch* to *develop* and make master point to *develop*.

**Question2**: Is there a better way? Merging them together (merge *new-branch* to *develop*) at this point is quite difficult and probably unnecessary - so I decided just to replace branches brutally.

Comment: `git checkout develop;git merge new-branch -s ours`. `-s ours` merges the history of new-branch into develop but introduces none of its code. Note that it's different from `-s recursive -X ours`.

Comment: Thanks, managed to use this for my 2nd question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch
`git checkout new-branch`  
`git merge -s ours develop`  
`git checkout develop`  
`git merge new-branch`  
`git checkout master`  
`git merge develop`

Comment: Question 1 is still active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not necessary version control them in git. You just need to **ignore the packages in [`.gitignore`](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) file**.

Detail steps as below:

1. In each branch, create a `.gitignore` file by `touch .gitignore`.
2. Add the files/paths of packages separately in `.gitignore` for each branch.

   Such as on `develop` branch, java package located in `a/b/*` of the root repo. On `new-branch`, java package located in `c/d/*`. You just add the relate files/paths in `.gitignore`.

   In `develop` branch, the content of `.gitignore` should be: `a/b/*`. In `new-branch`, the content of `.gitignore` should be `c/d/*`.
3. Commit changes on each branch.
4. Remove packages from version control history.

   In each branch, remove the package files/path you add in `.gitignore` by `git remove /path/or/file --cached`.

   Such as on `develop` branch, you can use `git rm a/b/* --cached`. on `new-branch`, you can use `git rm c/d/* --cached`.

If you need to version control the packages, you can use cherry-pick to apply the latest changes to another branch. Or merge/rebase a branch to another.

Comment: I think this doesn't help much in my case. Java packages was just an example. Merging single folder doesn't help my problem, as changes are usually across same files/folders but on different branches where each file/folder may have different structure.

Comment: So what's the reason for keeping files about the package totally in different structures?

Comment: For example, I might need this when migrating to new solution. I actually have Android project which uses Java packages and if you change just package name it infects lot of sources. Package change is just an example, sometimes there are other kinds of refactoring going on.

Comment: For this reason, do you want to keep the package folders are not be replaced when merging from another branch?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep all structure intact, just merge functional changes. Cherry picking seems to be only way as it just merges commit not entire branch.

Comment: You just need to add the files or paths of packages in `.gitignore`. And it's not necessary to version control them.

Comment: I can't remove my sources from version control as they are needed.

Comment: It's just remote the packages in version control. Actually the packages will still exist in current directories.

Comment: Of course I need them in repository for others to access.

Comment: If so, you should resolve the merge conflicts for the whole source. There is no way to merge part of files from one branch to another.

Comment: With cherry-pick I need to resolve only parts of code which are changed only in that commit.

Comment: Yeah, cherry-pick/rebase is also ok.