# How to switch the master branch with another branch along with their commits?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch

I have been working on a project using git. I have two branches master and feature. With the time I added more commits to the feature branch. And the feature branch is 5 commits ahead of master.

Now, I want to make the feature branch 'master'. And the master branch to a normal branch. There is a way to replace master branch with another branch in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch) using ours merge strategy, but the commits of the previous master are lost because the feature branch overrides them.

Is there a way to switch the master branch and the feature branch without loosing the commits of both branches?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to rename `master` branch to a normal branch (such as `Mybranch`) and rename `feature` branch to `master`. You can use below commands:

```
git branch -m master Mybranch
git branch -m feature master
```

To switch the remote branch based on the new branch name, you can use below commands:

```
#Change the remote master same as the new local master branch
git push -u origin master -f
#Push Mybranch to remote
git push -u origin Mybranch
#Delete remote feature branch
git push :feature
```

Comment: Lui - MSFT, Renaming is not the think I expected. Does it make any branch the master after renaming it as master?

Comment: The command `git branch -m feature master` will change the old `feature` branch as the new `master` branch.