# How replace a branch in Git with another branch without merge

Tags: git, merge

My repo structure is  like this.

- branch 'dev' -  Created from 'master' and is current.
- branch 'master' - No commits for last 2 years. But  few commits (unwanted) ahead of 'dev'.

Now my need is to make the 'master' code exactly same to 'dev'. I guess, a merge would cause the unwanted commits on 'master' to be retained. Any help?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/make-the-current-git-branch-a-master-branch (I won't close this as a duplicate since you specifically said "without merge" but those two contain what's probably a better way, i.e., *with* merge, but a merge that says "the other branch tip was right after all".)

Answer (score 6):

You may do a hard reset on `master` to the current `dev` branch:

```
# from master
git checkout master
git reset --hard dev
```

But keep in mind that this may potentially discard any commits on `master` which were unique to that branch.  If this be a concern of yours, then consider branching off from `master` as a safety precaution.

The next time you push `master` to the remote you will probably have to force push:

```
git push --force origin master
```

The reason for force pushing is that you have rewritten the base of the `master` branch and Git won't accept a regular push.

Comment: Thank you! No, I am not worried about the 'master' branch history.

Answer (score 1):

Tim's answer works great, let's just add this variant for the record :

```
# from any branch
git branch -f master dev
```

And the warning about losing the contents of the old dropped branch is the same, a backup is cheap, so maybe consider this :

```
git branch backup_old_master master
git branch -f master dev
```

Then `master` will point to the exact same commit (and history) `dev` currently points to, and you'll have `backup_old_master` just in case.

Comment: I like this answer better, because the working copy does not change twice. First the switches might take some time (in big repos) and - most important to me - automatic builders and IDEs don't start to do unnecessary work.