# How to completely replace master with another branch in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, devops

Using Azure DevOps, there is a repo with valid code being maintained in a secondary branch. However, the master branch is multiple years out of date.

I want to obliterate the contents of master and overwrite it with the contents of the secondary branch.

I understand that mishandling this can cause serious namespaces issues and I would like to avoid that.

What method would you recommend for completely replacing master with a secondary branch in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Is this a Git repo or a TFVC repo?

Comment: This is a "TFS GIT" repo. A GIT repo running inside Azure Devops.

Comment: If you don't want to keep the files in master anyway, I would just go for the easy way and [rename the branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2862606/3652378)

Comment: @Melisco - That works for me, but will it cause any longterm issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Clone the repo to your local machine.

   `git clone {repo url}`
2. Go to the local repo and move to the secondary branch.

   `git checkout {secondary branch}`
3. Copy all the content - `Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+C`.
4. Move back to master branch.

   `git checkout master`
5. Paste the files (and replace existing files) `Ctrl+V`.
6. Commit the changes.

   `git add .`

   `git commit -m "update master"`
7. Push the changes to Azure DevOps.

   `git push`

Now the `master` branch updated with the content of the `secondary branch`.

Comment: I was considering this... but since the master branch is stale by several years, will this cause any issues when master is updated with the secondary branch? Based on what I read, I should consider using the -f flag if I chose this method... is that correct?

Comment: clone the repo, copy him for backup, try what I suggested, succeed? good. not? try `-f` :)

Comment: Step 3 should be "copy all files except the .git folder to a temp location
Step 4 should be "Copy all  the  files from step 3 from the temp location and paste them over existing files.

Changed behaviour in Windows makes this procedure do nothing if you do not use a physical temp location

Comment: is this really the best option? only option? because you'd still have all that history of old commits, I would like to take a snapshot in time, before a series of bad commits, and promote that new master.

Comment: @nagates did you find better way to have history of old commits?