# Git - force a rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I have a situation where my master branch is way, way behind another branch.  I'd like to simply more or less obliterate the old master and have the other branch be, essentially, a new master.

I'm the only one working on this project, and the old master has very little in common with the new/current branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace master branch in Git, entirely, from another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+replace+master+current+branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about the old history at all:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard the-other-branch-i-want-as-master
```

That will delete all changes you have laying around your working tree so use with care.... if what you would like instead is a new revision where you set your working tree as a new revision on your old master:

```
git checkout the-other-branch --detach
git reset --soft master
git commit -m "Single change to move old master to a new position where I want it"
git branch -f master
git checkout master
```

Comment: Upvoted for the second solution which is arguably the most useful and elegant way to achieve the goal while keeping a clear history of what's been made.

Comment: If I push to origin master, which has the outdated code, will it just accept the revision bomb (for lack of a better term), or will I need to do more to ensure the remote doesn't complain?

Comment: If you reset --hard (or branch -f, as others have suggested), you are rewriting history (revisions on the old branch might disappear)... that will require you to use `git push -f`.

Comment: By default remote will not accept changes in history. So you will need push force (-f) or rebase new commits on top of original master. But it is not match question and situation where only you are working in repo.

Comment: If you _have_ to keep the old history, then I think you should consider using the `reset --soft` recipe I provided. You will get one revision on top of your old history with all changes required to get your old branch to look like the new branch (with a single unrelated revision).

Comment: The soft reset was the best of both worlds (getting the rebase I wanted without completely obliterating the commit history (while saving it wasn't a priority, it's nice to keep that intact, too))... thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

If so, the simplest way probably is to just move the reference :

```
git branch -f master <nameOfTheUpToDateBranch>
```

([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---force))

Answer (score 1):

This is may be achieved with two very simple methods. Either:

```sh
  git checkout master
  git reset --hard my-branch
```

or in any other branch which is not the master branch:

```sh
  git branch -f master my-branch
```