# Rename the master but preserve branch history

Tags: git, github

I have a branch I want to rename as master. I have been working on, branching from, and creating pull requests from this branch. My current master is broken as it somehow has a different history than the repo I forked from. I tried cloning into a different folder and the same problem persists.

I wish to keep the history of the branch I have been working from as well as all of the branches I created from it. I can completely wipe out the current master and completely replace its history.  I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/make-the-current-git-branch-a-master-branch) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch) resource, but I am unsure as to what happens to the history of the branches once you switch. Also I am the only one who has been working on this remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that branches in git are just **pointers to revisions**, that you can shuffle around at will so keep the old broken master and then rename your branch as master, no problem with that

```
git checkout master
git branch -m broken-master
git checkout the-other-branch
git branch -m master
```