# Git branch merge not working as I expect in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I'm struggling with git merge. I have an initial commit to the master branch. I created a new branch from it -- call it foo -- and did some work on that branch. Everything is fine and I commit changes, so I'd like to make that branch the master. So (in Visual Studio) I checkout the master branch, do merge from foo, and nothing changes - the master branch is just as it was. So how *do* I get my changes into my master branch?

If I open a console, checkout master, and do `git merge foo`, everything works as I expect, so this is a Visual Studio behaviour I don't understand.

Comment: Similar question's answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/2862938/10325025] . Perfectly explained the process.

Comment: No, that doesn't relate to my question at all. As I said in the question, everything works exactly as expected - and as described in that answer - from the command line. My problem is that it doesn't work like that in the Visual Studio 2019 interface.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled in the same problem on my work PC with an old version o VisualStudio.

I've resolved by updating to the latest version as per:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1000804/git-merge-does-not-work.html