# Git merge "develop", replace all with the "develop" version

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I have a `master` (main) branch  and a `develop` branch with another code.

We realized that all the code from the `master` is obsolete and should be entirely *replaced* by the the `develop` branch (clean `develop`, without any additional `master` files, any merge).

`master` should remain the main (production) branch

Automatic merge failed because of conflicts.

[image]

Edit: after Eric's sugestion I did the following

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard develop
git push --force
```

And obtained:

[image]

> fatal: You are not currently on a branch. To push the history leading
> to the current (detached HEAD) state now, use
>
> ```
> git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
> ```

and this

[image]

Comment: Why did it fail? On which files? Have you tried fixing merge conflicts manually? That's going to happen sometimes.

Comment: I don't need to resolve any conflict, I just need to replace my master with the develop version.

Answer (score 1):

1. Checkout master (`git checkout master`)
2. Reset to develop (`git reset --hard develop`)
3. Force push (`git push --force`)

This tells git to make `master` point to the same commit as `develop`. You need to force-push, because you are changing the history of `master`. After the steps your `master` will be the same as `develop`.

Be careful though. I would record the current commit IDs of `develop` and `master` to be able to go back to the previous state, in case the result turns out not to be what you want.

Comment: updated the OP with he above command result

Comment: now I don't know if I should do `git push origin HEAD:develop` or `HEAD:master`

Comment: Also, I need that the master branch remain be the main one, not the develop

Comment: it is still the main branch. While on `master`  `git push --force origin master`to also make `origin/master` the same as your local `master`

Comment: Ah, I see your problem. Before doing the push, do another `git checkout master`

Comment: now, I can do anything before the push ) because I already did the push

Comment: I try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/2862938/961631