# How can replace azure Remote Branch toanother remote Branch Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, devops, git-remote

I have a `xyz` remote Branch in Azure Devops and I want to replace `master` Remote Branch with this Branch.

Meaning: My master Remote Branch data will be replaced with `XYZ` Branch.
How is it Possible ?

Answer (score 0):

One easy approach is to:

- clone your DevOps Azure repository locally
- rename your master branch to old, rename your XYZ branch to master
- force push

See this approach [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2862606/6309).
But that would replace all commits from masters by the ones from XYZ.

If you just want to replace master files, while keeping its original history, [use `git merge -s ours` (as seen here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2862938/6309)

In both instances, making sure the end result is the one you expect locally, before pushing back, is the recommended approach.