# Merge of rebase causes commits to be overwritten

Tags: git

We had an old branch, feature-x, and we tried merging in a recent master. In the merge we saw that a bunch of the commits from the feature-x branch had been overwritten, and the code had disappeared. I'm now cherry-picking the relevant commits into a fresh branch off master, but I was wondering why this happens. Anecdotally this also happened to me in SVK... is there something we're doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That should mean those commits were already merged at some point in `master`.
Meaning any future merge won't pick them. And cherry-pick is then a way to force them back (again) in `master`.

A radical solution would involve a merge with an ['our' merge stategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295171/git-merge-to-master-while-automatically-choosing-to-overwrite-master-files-with), [albeit in reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/git-merge-s-ours-what-about-their). (but that would then override all files from `master` with those of `feature-x`)