# How do I merge multiple branches into master?

Tags: git

```
        C---D  =>b1
      /    
     /  E---F  =>b2
     | /   
  A--B =======> master
     | \
     \  G---H  =>b3
      \ 
       I---J   =>b4
```

I want to merge `b1`,`b2`,`b3`,`b4` into `master`, is it possible merge at once?

something like:

```
git checkout master
git merge b1 b2 b3 b4
```

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_merge_strategies See octopus and below.

Comment: Why you not just try it by yourself. It can work if there is no conflict.

Comment: @android, since there's already an answer recommending bash usage and another claiming that it simply isn't possible, I think you should rewrite that comment as an answer, because it's actually correct, while the others so far are not.

Comment: @KyleStrand Yeah, seeing that no one bothered to research the topic, I've finally decided to do so myself.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Git's `merge` command supports multiple [merging strategies](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_merge_strategies). There are two strategies that can merge more than two branches at a time.

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366860/when-would-you-use-the-different-git-merge-strategies) for a less formal description of each one.

#### octopus

> This resolves cases with more than two
>   heads, but refuses to do a complex merge that needs manual resolution.
>   It is primarily meant to be used for bundling topic branch heads
>   together. This is the default merge strategy when pulling or merging
>   more than one branch.

The last statement implies that if you do `git merge branch1 branch2 ...`, it'll use the **octopus** strategy.

#### ours

> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring
>   all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to
>   supersede old development history of side branches.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295171/git-merge-to-master-while-automatically-choosing-to-overwrite-master-files-with) for a use case example.

Answer (score 3):

Git has a merging strategy called octupus which can merge multiple branches, as long as there are no complex conflicts. The command to do this is exactly as you suggested `git merge b1 b2`.

Comment: this is not quite true. the octopus merge strategy can merge an arbitrary number of branches

Comment: As is said it was the short answer, the octopus strategy only works if there are no complex merges. It will fail if there are any conflicts. And still can't do it in one command, like requested.

Comment: Actually, you **can** merge multiple branches in one command. The [Git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) give this as an example: `$git merge fixes enhancements`.

Comment: Ah, that's true. I've always thought that merged fixes into enchancements.