# How to tag multiple tags into a single tag?

Tags: git

I am using git and was wondering whether there is a way pick multiple tags at once and create a new release tag. I know I can definitely merge two tags like this :

```
git checkout <tag-1>
git merge <tag-2>
```

But is it possible to merge multiple tags to a single tag using one command?

Comment: did you read this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979642/how-to-checkout-remote-git-tag

Comment: Not sure how it is related to the other question. I am not looking for how to checkout tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question does not make that much sense for me. A tag is a label for commit, or branches. Or you can consider it as bookmark in the history of a repo.

[Checking out Tags](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_git_tagging)

Let's say, you need to have a new branch called `newBranchName` with starting point of `myTag` which is your tag.

```
git checkout -b newBranchName myTag
```

This would make a branch based on your tag.

---

**Is it possible to merge multiple tags to a single tag using one command?**

No.Can you have several starting point for a branch?

The tags are just labels, ***what you can merge is the branches***, therefore you can make branches for tags and then try to perform your merge, the question is **can i merge multiple branches** . And the answer is below

[How do I merge multiple branches into master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208144/how-do-i-merge-multiple-branches-into-master)

Comment: Your answer make sense. I was sort of breaking the git-flow. Is there a way I can freeze this question?

Comment: @user_dev Unfortunately not, because I already answered you. It's ok to leave it as it is. It showed that, you think about something and raised a question. So,  this question contributes to the stackoverflow community, why do you want to close it?
And i would be grateful, if you accept the answer.