# Merging multiple branches in Git

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a repository. From the main branch i have created branches as in the illustration.
Also before making any changes to the branches, I've made 3 commits to the main branch.  After completing changes with main branch, I've branched 2 more branches from BranchA in a transitive fashion.  Now i want to merge the Branches A,B and C to main branch.  Is it possible to do?

[image: I have a repository. From the main branch i have created branches as in the illustration. Also before making any changes to the branches, I've made 3 commits to the main branch. After completing changes with main branch, I've branched 2 more branches from BranchA in a transitive fashion. Now i want to merge the Branches A,B and C to main branch. Is it possible to do?]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge multiple branches into master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208144/how-do-i-merge-multiple-branches-into-master)

Comment: As a side note, main should not be there in your chart... `main` is a pointer to commit3, actually.... and arrows should be setup in the opposite direction (if I understand your chart correctly), because in git children commits point to parent commits, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Given `branchC` is on top of `branchB` which is on top of `branchA`, you could get it all in by just merging `branchC` into `main`. You could just as well merge each one after the other, first `branchA`, then `branchB`, then `branchC` but it would be the same result in terms of *content*... so, it really depends on what you would like your *history* to look like:

```
* merging branchC <- (main)
|\
| * 3rd commit branchC <- (branchC)
| * 2nd commit branchC
| * 1st commit branchC
| * 3rd commit branchB <- (branchB)
| * 2nd commit branchB
| * 1st commit branchB
| * 3rd commit branchA <- (branchA)
| * 2nd commit branchA
| * 1st commit branchA
* | commit 3
* | commit 2
* | commit 1
|/
* initial commit
```

Or

```
* merging branchC <- (main)
|\
| * 3rd commit branchC <- (branchC)
| * 2nd commit branchC
| * 1st commit branchC
* | Merging branch B
|\|
| * 3rd commit branchB <- (branchB)
| * 2nd commit branchB
| * 1st commit branchB
* | Merging branch A
|\|
| * 3rd commit branchA <- (branchA)
| * 2nd commit branchA
| * 1st commit branchA
* | commit 3
* | commit 2
* | commit 1
|/
* initial commit
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure those commits in main branch are pushed to remote. Merge branch C to branch B, then merge Branch B to Branch A. Remote `main` branch have some commit updates that are not in your local repository. So, checkout to main branch and apply `git pull origin main`. Now, checkout to branch A. rebase master onto your current branch.
`git rebase main`
Resolve if any conflict arises and complete the rebase operation. Force push your branch to remote. Finally, merge branch A with main.