# git merge into master only overwrite changed files

Tags: git, merge

Is it possible to merge branch `edits` into branch `master` with the following scenario:

many changes were made on `edits` as well as new files added.

many changes were also made to `master` as well as new files added.

I'd like to overwrite any duplicate files in `master` and use the files from `edits`, so that when im done, `master` will contain all changes from `edits`, all new files from `edits` and all new files from `master`. If both contained new files, it would use `edits`'s new files. If there are merges, I'd like to replace the **entire** file with the one from `edits`.

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1295232/1166285 and tried the comment's suggestion but that made conflicts which i'd have to resolve.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the `master` branch, merge in the `edits` branch with the `theirs` merge strategy:

```
git checkout master
git merge -Xtheirs edits
```

In case of conflicts, this will prefer the `theirs` branch. Changes from `master` where there is no conflict will be retained.

Comment: thanks, does this replace the file completely if there are *some* conflicts?

Comment: If a single file contains changes on both branches, the ones that do not conflict will make it into the merged file.

Comment: this ended with `Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the results`

Comment: That's surprising!  Was the master branch clean, or did it have uncommitted changes?  (Check with `git status`.)  What kind of changes caused the conflicts?  (Check with `git diff --diff-filter=U`)

Comment: git status only has untracked files (in both), and the other command showed nothing

Comment: The second command displays the merge conflicts.  It should show something after an automatic merge fails.

Comment: oh b/c I did a git reset --hard afterwards. That second command would show `* Unmerged path html/file.php`

Comment: It was because i renamed a file to the same name but all uppercase. Doing `git add -u` afterwards fix it...thanks!