# Git resolve conflict using --ours/--theirs for all files

Tags: git, conflict, resolve, merge-conflict-resolution

Is there a way to resolve conflict for all files using checkout `--ours` and `--theirs`? I know that you can do it for individual files but couldn't find a way to do it for all.

Comment: Does `git checkout --ours -- .` work? The `.` means the current directory, when applied from the working directory root, so it basically means the entire working directory. Not sure if that will work with the `--ours` flag though, and I'm not sure how it will handle deleted or renamed file conflicts.

Comment: @Cupcake I've used it successfully. Maybe that should be an answer?

Comment: If someone is looking for an answer to do this in Visual Studio, take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74605102/8644294

Answer (score 118):

Just grep through the working directory and send the output through the xargs command:

```
grep -lr '<<<<<<<' . | xargs git checkout --ours
```

or

```
grep -lr '<<<<<<<' . | xargs git checkout --theirs
```

How this works: `grep` will search through every file in the current directory (the `.`) and subdirectories recursively (the `-r` flag) looking for conflict markers (the string '<<<<<<<')

the `-l` or `--files-with-matches` flag causes grep to output only the filename where the string was found. Scanning stops after first match, so  each matched file is only output once.

The matched file names are then [piped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) to [xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs), a utility that breaks up the piped input stream into individual arguments for `git checkout --ours` or `--theirs`

More [at this link](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/git/git-resolve-merge-conflicts/).

Since it would be very inconvenient to have to type this every time at the command line, if you do find yourself using it a lot, it might not be a bad idea to create an [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)) for your shell of choice: [Bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) is the usual one.

This method should work through at least Git versions [2.4.x](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Comment: Instead of grepping, I think it’s also possible to use [`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10874862/559913).

Comment: Also `git status | grep both | awk '{print $3}' | xargs git checkout --[theirs|ours]`.  Quicker than grepping if you have a large project.

Comment: @joshbodily Nice. I don't have projects so huge that I would notice a difference, but I can see how it would be much faster especially if few files have changed compared to the total number in the directory----which _should_ be the case for normal commits.

Comment: Note that this does not work for rename/rename conflicts, e.g., `CONFLICT (rename/rename): Rename "a.txt"->"c.txt" in branch "HEAD" rename "a.txt"->"b.txt" in "master"`

Comment: Yet another option: `git status --porcelain | egrep '^UU' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 |xargs git checkout --[theirs|ours]`.

Comment: Did not work probably because of spaces in my directory names

Comment: @AbdulHannan: You can escape the spaces in your filenames with a backslash: `file\ name\ with\ spaces.txt`
Or, enclose all pathnames in double quotes:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Comment: @dimitri. Thats clear to me but how above answer can be made to work with directories containing spaces?

Comment: @AbdulHannan It shouldn't make a difference: grep should spit out an argument into the pipe that xargs + git can understand. At least it does on a UN*X system. Are you trying this on Windows?

Comment: Tried it on mac, will update you with what error I got exactly

Comment: I had filenames with spaces and single quotes and I had to use the -z option on git diff in conjunction with the -0 option on xargs to get it to work. `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U -z | xargs -0 git checkout --theirs`

Comment: For big projects this is really slow, it would also add jpegs and other files that didn't have conflicts. @Peter 's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 86):

You can `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs` with `git merge` as well. So:

1. abort the current merge (for instance with `git reset --hard HEAD`)
2. merge using the strategy you prefer (`git merge -Xours` or `git merge -Xtheirs`)

DISCLAIMER: of course you can choose only one option, either `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs`, do use different strategy you should of course go file by file.

I do not know if there is a way for `checkout`, but I do not honestly think it is terribly useful: selecting the strategy with the checkout command is useful if you want different solutions for different files, otherwise just go for the merge strategy approach.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know they have '--ours' and '--theirs' for merge. It seems that for merge they are actually not part of '-s' strategy but part of '-X' recursive options. '-s' version of ours actually just replaces all files without merging and theirs doesn't exist.

Comment: There is no `--theirs` or `--ours`-Option to git v1.9.4. An approach would be `git merge -s recursive -Xtheirs BRANCH`.

Comment: `--theirs` and `--ours` are not available neither with git `2.2.0`. Either my answer was not precise or they were available in older git version (this answer is pretty old in IT epoch). The right approach is with `-X`. I update accordingly

Comment: As of Version 2.4.0  --ours and --theirs are still very much available
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: Tried this, and got "automatic merge failed, fix conflicts". This command clearly doesn't work as intended, and I recommend avoiding it - too buggy.

Comment: Also works when `rebase`ing, although the identities of `ours` and `theirs` is switched (`Xours` means keep the changes from the branch being rebased **onto**).

Answer (score 63):

`git checkout --[ours/theirs] .` will do what you want, as long as you're at the root of all conflicts. ours/theirs only affects unmerged files so you shouldn't have to grep/find/etc conflicts specifically.

Comment: For me this doesn't seem to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: I get `error: path 'foo/bar/blah' does not have our version`.

Comment: I'm using git version 2.16.2.windows.1 and it works perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `git restore [--ours] [--theirs] [--staged] <pathspec>`

Comment: `$ git checkout --ours` gives:
`fatal: '--ours/--theirs' cannot be used with switching branches`.  `git version 2.31.1
hub version 2.14.2`

Answer (score 43):

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs git checkout --theirs
```

Seems to do the job.  Note that you have to be cd'ed to the root directory of the git repo to achieve this.

Comment: I think this is a better answer than the top-voted one because (1) it applies to all files, not just the working directory; and (2) it won't have any brittleness around grepping for conflict markers.  The 'git diff' command here lists all unmerged paths, which is exactly what we want to checkout.

Comment: Nice! I was always concerned about the reliability of the conflict markers grep

Comment: I pieced exactly this together from above answers. Agreed this is the cleanest + most performant (the `grep` option is really a non-starter for larger projects, esp JS projects with sizeable `node_modules` folders). I ended up adding these aliases to my `.bashrc`:
```
alias git-co-ours="git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs git checkout --ours"
alias git-co-theirs="git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs git checkout --theirs"
```

Comment: You can use add `--relative` to diff `git diff --relative` to make the paths relative, then it works from any subdirectory.

Answer (score 26):

**Scenario 1**

In case anyone else is looking to simply overwrite everything in one branch (e.g. `master`) with the contents of another branch, there's an easier way:

```
git merge origin/master --strategy=ours
```

(The `--strategy` option also works with `git pull`.)

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1295232/560114

**Scenario 2**

For the other way around, see [Is there a "theirs" version of "git merge -s ours"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/is-there-a-theirs-version-of-git-merge-s-ours)

***Update***

For scenario 2, the linked answer recommends using:

```
git checkout branchA
git merge -X theirs branchB
```

I have found that this is not exactly the reverse of `--strategy=ours` and you might still get merge conflicts (and in some cases code from the other branch being kept that you actually wanted to remove). So if you want a solution to truly do the opposite of `git merge other-branch --strategy=ours`, the best way is to do it in two steps (two merges). Suppose your goal is to replace `branch-a` with the contents of `branch-b`. Then the first step would be to do this:

```
git checkout branch-b
git fetch branch-a
git merge branch-a --strategy=ours
```

Now branch-b is ready to merge into branch-a without conflicts. At this point, if you're using something like Github, you could raise a PR to merge branch-b into branch-a. Or if no peer review is required, you could do the merge directly:

```
git checkout branch-a
git merge branch-b

# Cleanup - delete branch-b (if desired)
git branch -d branch-b
git push origin --delete branch-b
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function gitcheckoutall() {
    git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' | xargs git checkout --$1
}
```

I've added this function in **.zshrc** file.

Use them this way:
`gitcheckoutall theirs` or `gitcheckoutall ours`

Answer (score 0):

Its simply one of these...

```
git checkout --ours .
git checkout --theirs .
```