# Git merge and ovewrite from tag

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-merge, git-squash

I'm trying to keep 2 separated branches on git, the "Dev" on which I work and the "Master" which is basically a clean branch where I push clean versions of my project.

The problem here is that I don't want any history from previous commit when I merge. I, kind of, figured out how to do it and it worked juste fine for the first merge but now (on my second one) I'm having troubles with a lot merge conflicts.

Here is what I previously did :

> git checkout dev
>
> git tag -a 1.0 -m "version 1.0"
>
> git push origin --tags
>
> git checkout master
>
> git merge --squash 1.0
>
> git commit "message"
>
> git push origin master

So it worked the first time when the master branch was totally clean but now, I get a lot a merge conflicts.
Is there a way to force merge every changes there is on the tag 1.0 to master ? Or a better way to do all of this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: Merge to master while automatically choosing to overwrite master files with branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295171/git-merge-to-master-while-automatically-choosing-to-overwrite-master-files-with)

Comment: @Robray, did the answer help you to solve the problem? If yes, please mark it (on the left of answer). And it can help more people with similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try one of the commands below to solve the merge conflicts automatically:

```
git merge -X theirs --squash 1.0
git merge -X ours --squash 1.0
```

And then use `git commit -m 'message'`.