# Merge the branch to master (over-write of forced)

Tags: git, merge, branch

I dont have access to commit the code directly in 'master'. I need to merge the code from 'branch' to 'master'.
I have to over-write or replace the existing changes in 'master'.
I am trying the steps given in this thread. [Git: Merge to master while automatically choosing to overwrite master files with branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295171/git-merge-to-master-while-automatically-choosing-to-overwrite-master-files-with)

Can you anyone suggest any steps to over-write the changes in master from branch

Comment: can't you just open a Pull Request, see the changes, solve conflicts and then approve and merge? If your master is protected, that's the standard way to go.

Comment: Thanks. this worked (after trying this - https://coderwall.com/p/ffz7xg/overwrite-master-branch-with-current-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just formulating an answer based on my comment - which apparently was worthy...

To follow the standard way to go, you should open a Pull Request. This way you can see the changes, solve the conflicts, get your request approved (protected repositories require that) and, finally, merged to the master.

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/ffz7xg/overwrite-master-branch-with-current-branch-in-git