# Git merge using recursive strategy and patience option

Tags: git

How to merge a branch with git using patience option provided by the recursive strategy? I'm using
git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0

Even docs are not consistent and, what's more, differ from what the actual command outputs.

[Docs say:](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)

> git merge [-s `<strategy>`] [-X `<strategy-option>`] `<commit>`

and further in text:

> -X`<option>`

(no space)

Output from the command says:

```
-X, --strategy-option <option=value>

option for selected merge strategy
```

So I tried a couple versions with following results:

```
$ git merge -s recursive -Xpatience sourceBranch
fatal: Unknown option for merge-recursive: -Xpatience

$ git merge -X patience sourceBranch
fatal: Unknown option for merge-recursive: -Xpatience

$ git merge -Xpatience sourceBranch
fatal: Unknown option for merge-recursive: -Xpatience

$ git merge --strategy-option patience sourceBranch
fatal: Unknown option for merge-recursive: -Xpatience

$ git merge -X option=patience sourceBranch
fatal: Unknown option for merge-recursive: -Xoption=patience

$ git merge --strategy-option option=patience sourceBranch
fatal: Unknown option for merge-recursive: -Xoption=patience

$ git merge option=patience sourceBranch
fatal: 'option=patience' does not point to a commit

$ git merge -X option=patience sourceBranch
fatal: Unknown option for merge-recursive: -Xoption=patience
```

It looks as if the option's not implemented...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `--patience` option for `git merge-recursive` was introduced in commit [`58a1ece478c6038a7eb0b6e494d563bd5e6d5978`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58a1ece478c6038a7eb0b6e494d563bd5e6d5978).  You can find out in a clone of `git.git` what versions contain this change with `git tag --contains 58a1ece478`:

```
v1.7.4
v1.7.4-rc0
v1.7.4-rc1
v1.7.4-rc2
v1.7.4-rc3
v1.7.4.1
```

So I suspect that you're just using a slightly too old version of mSysGit.  There is a preview version of 1.7.4 available now - I think you should try that one.

I've just tried this with git version 1.7.4, and the following command line syntax works for me:

```
git merge -s recursive -X patience other-branch
```

Comment: Updating from 1.7.3. to 1.7.4 (which came out just 3 weeks ago in mSysGit) helped! Thanks for detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

Update Aug. 2021, 10 years later: no more "recursive merge":

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), the **default** merge strategy becomes [ORT ("Ostensibly Recursive's Twin")](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64950077/6309)

See [commit 81483fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81483fe613de70e17913167876676528cb37cbcd), [commit 67feccd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67feccd3ba4566392774b8ed9492d7169031d4bb), [commit 6320813](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6320813bc0daf03f087072a498b5aaa8bbba36bd), [commit b36ade2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b36ade216c4a72dda6b8e3006cd3ded44ece1c66), [commit 4d15c85](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d15c85556891bfdddfb90b6be056b08079696bb), [commit 002a6df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/002a6dfc7c4642524d1e82f8cf994fc9ea5786f9), [commit 510415e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/510415ecc9d6ff4a99991dc1b70a1ac50818a539), [commit e80178e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e80178eac6f3513bed7ec7ead9d5b0ebfa429241), [commit b378df7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b378df72ed147d346503341db06771c52cd2dbb8), [commit e037c2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e037c2e41869489c1e17701a9f1c429ad9c18f9b) (04 Aug 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit aca13c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aca13c2355e7188432cb32aedf0bb0c477ec011a), 30 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`81483fe613`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81483fe613de70e17913167876676528cb37cbcd):Update error message and code comment
>
> <sup>Acked-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> There were two locations in the code that referred to 'merge-recursive' but which were also applicable to 'merge-ort'.
> Update them to more general wording.

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), documentation updates.

See [commit 81483fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81483fe613de70e17913167876676528cb37cbcd), [commit 67feccd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67feccd3ba4566392774b8ed9492d7169031d4bb), [commit 6320813](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6320813bc0daf03f087072a498b5aaa8bbba36bd), [commit b36ade2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b36ade216c4a72dda6b8e3006cd3ded44ece1c66), [commit 4d15c85](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d15c85556891bfdddfb90b6be056b08079696bb), [commit 002a6df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/002a6dfc7c4642524d1e82f8cf994fc9ea5786f9), [commit 510415e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/510415ecc9d6ff4a99991dc1b70a1ac50818a539), [commit e80178e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e80178eac6f3513bed7ec7ead9d5b0ebfa429241), [commit b378df7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b378df72ed147d346503341db06771c52cd2dbb8), [commit e037c2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e037c2e41869489c1e17701a9f1c429ad9c18f9b) (04 Aug 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit aca13c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aca13c2355e7188432cb32aedf0bb0c477ec011a), 30 Aug 2021)</sup>

`merge-strategies` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/67feccd3ba4566392774b8ed9492d7169031d4bb/Documentation/merge-strategies.txt#L98-L111):

> ### `ort`
>
> This is meant as a drop-in replacement for the `recursive`
> algorithm (as reflected in its acronym -- "Ostensibly
> Recursive's Twin"), and will likely replace it in the future.
>
> It fixes corner cases that the `recursive` strategy handles
> suboptimally, and is significantly faster in large
> repositories -- especially when many renames are involved.
>
> The `ort` strategy takes all the same options as `recursive`.
> However, it ignores three of those options: `no-renames`,
> `patience` and `diff-algorithm`.
> It always runs with rename
> detection (it handles it much faster than `recursive` does), and
> it specifically uses `diff-algorithm=histogram`.

And:

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), use `ort` instead of `recursive` as the default merge strategy.

See [commit f5a3c5e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5a3c5e6377b806c320e4220ba26e467b4c4e992), [commit 6a5fb96](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a5fb966720fffaae28bbd9408c55414c3b8c813) (04 Aug 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8778fa8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8778fa8b4f18a3930101825e5bcff62b5348e918), 30 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`f5a3c5e637`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5a3c5e6377b806c320e4220ba26e467b4c4e992):Update docs for change of default merge backend
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> Make it clear that `ort` is the default merge strategy now rather than `recursive`, including moving `ort` to the front of the list of merge strategies.

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5a3c5e6377b806c320e4220ba26e467b4c4e992/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L369):

> specified, `-s ort`.  Note the reversal of 'ours' and

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5a3c5e6377b806c320e4220ba26e467b4c4e992/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L1219-L1228):

> By default, the `merge` command will use the `ort` merge strategy for
> regular merges, and `octopus` for octopus merges.
> One can specify a
> default strategy for all merges using the `--strategy` argument when
> invoking rebase, or can override specific merges in the interactive
> list of commands by using an `exec` command to call `git merge`
> explicitly with a `--strategy` argument.
> Note that when calling `git merge` explicitly like this, you can make use of the fact that the
> labels are worktree-local refs (the ref `refs/rewritten/onto` would
> correspond to the label `onto`, for example) in order to refer to the
> branches you want to merge.

`gitfaq` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5a3c5e6377b806c320e4220ba26e467b4c4e992/Documentation/gitfaq.txt#L278):

> By default, when Git does a merge, it uses a strategy called the `ort`

`merge-strategies` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5a3c5e6377b806c320e4220ba26e467b4c4e992/Documentation/merge-strategies.txt#L9-L23):

> ### `ort`
>
> This is the default merge strategy when pulling or merging one
> branch.
>
> This strategy can only resolve two heads using a
> 3-way merge algorithm.
> When there is more than one common
> ancestor that can be used for 3-way merge, it creates a merged
> tree of the common ancestors and uses that as the reference
> tree for the 3-way merge.
>
> This has been reported to result in
> fewer merge conflicts without causing mismerges by tests done
> on actual merge commits taken from Linux 2.6 kernel
> development history.
>
> Additionally this strategy can detect and handle merges involving renames.
> It does not make use of detected copies.
>
> The name for this algorithm is an acronym
> ("Ostensibly Recursive's Twin") and came from the fact that it
> was written as a replacement for the previous default
> algorithm, `recursive`.

`merge-strategies` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5a3c5e6377b806c320e4220ba26e467b4c4e992/Documentation/merge-strategies.txt#L25):

> The 'ort' strategy can take the following options:
>
> ### `recursive`
>
> This can only resolve two heads using a 3-way merge
> algorithm.
> When there is more than one common
> ancestor that can be used for 3-way merge, it creates a
> merged tree of the common ancestors and uses that as
> the reference tree for the 3-way merge.
>
> This has been
> reported to result in fewer merge conflicts without
> causing mismerges by tests done on actual merge commits
> taken from Linux 2.6 kernel development history.
>
> Additionally this can detect and handle merges involving
> renames.
> It does not make use of detected copies.  This was
> the default strategy for resolving two heads from Git v0.99.9k
> until v2.33.0.
> The 'recursive' strategy takes the same options as 'ort'.
> However,
> there are three additional options that 'ort' ignores (not documented
> above) that are potentially useful with the 'recursive' strategy:
>
> ### patience;;
>
> Deprecated synonym for `diff-algorithm=patience`.
>
> ### no-renames;;
>
> Turn off rename detection. This overrides the `merge.renames`
> configuration variable.

---

Original answer (2011)

I [see here the patch](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg138778.html) introducing the patience option to the recursive merge strategy, base on Git1.7.2.2, but I don't see it in any of the subsequent release notes.

Yet the patience diff algorithm has been presented since 2009, and is [detailed here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Bram-Cohen-speaks-up-about-patience-diff-td2277041.html).

```
> grep -i patience *.c
diff.c: else if (!strcmp(arg, "--patience"))
diff.c:         DIFF_XDL_SET(options, PATIENCE_DIFF);
merge-recursive.c:      else if (!strcmp(s, "patience"))
merge-recursive.c:              o->xdl_opts |= XDF_PATIENCE_DIFF;
```

The merge command should understand this option... but this function below seems to never be called (not anywhere in `merge-recursive.c` or in any other `*.c` file!):

```
int parse_merge_opt(struct merge_options *o, const char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s)
        return -1;
    if (!strcmp(s, "ours"))
        o->recursive_variant = MERGE_RECURSIVE_OURS;
    else if (!strcmp(s, "theirs"))
        o->recursive_variant = MERGE_RECURSIVE_THEIRS;
    else if (!strcmp(s, "subtree"))
        o->subtree_shift = "";
    else if (!prefixcmp(s, "subtree="))
        o->subtree_shift = s + strlen("subtree=");
    else if (!strcmp(s, "patience"))
        o->xdl_opts |= XDF_PATIENCE_DIFF;
    else if (!strcmp(s, "ignore-space-change"))
        o->xdl_opts |= XDF_IGNORE_WHITESPACE_CHANGE;
    else if (!strcmp(s, "ignore-all-space"))
        o->xdl_opts |= XDF_IGNORE_WHITESPACE;
    else if (!strcmp(s, "ignore-space-at-eol"))
        o->xdl_opts |= XDF_IGNORE_WHITESPACE_AT_EOL;
    else if (!strcmp(s, "renormalize"))
        o->renormalize = 1;
    else if (!strcmp(s, "no-renormalize"))
        o->renormalize = 0;
    else if (!prefixcmp(s, "rename-threshold=")) {
        const char *score = s + strlen("rename-threshold=");
        if ((o->rename_score = parse_rename_score(&score)) == -1 || *score != 0)
            return -1;
    }
    else
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

The "Unknown option" error message is only printed by the `handle_options` function in `git.c`.
And `XDF_PATIENCE_DIFF` doesn't show anywhere else in git sources (1.7.4)... so yes, I don't know how this could be implemented for the merge.

Comment: @Filip: I only suggest I don't understand how the code currently uses the options for the merge strategy (but my skills in C aren't exactly stellar to begin with).

Comment: in 1.7.4, `parse_merge_opt` is called from both `merge.c` and `merge-recursive.c`.  However, @Filip is using 1.7.3.1 in any case.  The commit that introduced the `patience` option for merging is only present in 1.7.4 - see my answer...