# Git: currently in merge/conflict with private remote repo. How to tell Git to just use my local files?

Tags: git, merge, conflict, merge-conflict-resolution

Trying to use/learn git with a personal project. There's only me and a remote git repo, a few commits, and I'm stuck in a failed merge. A lot of my files have Git merge conflict markup now too.

How do I tell git to just throw everything out, just use mine?

A specific example of how I got into the state I'm in:

```
echo A new file > myFile.txt             # example file
git add myFile.txt                       # add file
git commit                               # commit changes
git push                                 # push changes to remote repo
echo A conflicting edit > myFile.txt     # oh, no, forgot some changes
git add myFile.txt                       # add again
git commit --amend                       # amend previous commit
git push                                 # fails. Git suggests to do a pull first
git pull origin HEAD                     # "Automatic merge failed" Now what?
                                         # Just use what I have locally!
```

Comment: Yeah. Didn't find a simple "use my local everything" command.

Comment: Git merge conflicts are solved in this mega thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git

Comment: Yeah, found that thread. It didn't help me. They talked about using tools I couldn't use (`git mergetool`), looking at verbose documentation, general advice about how to avoid merges, etc. When I Googled for "Git use local", I kept finding articles about how to use git on my computer without a remote origin. It's infuriating. Are you saying there isn't a one-line command that just tells git to "use my local"?

Comment: This is nowhere close to an "Exact Duplicate" of the "git merge megathread". This a specific merge scenario, and as such, better to have it here than lost in the noise of a mega thread with 10 responses and a 100 comments.

Comment: @mehaase Thanks! This was exactly what I was hoping for

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
git checkout --ours . # checkout our local version of all files
git add -u            # mark all conflicted files as merged/resolved
git commit            # commit the merge
```

There is a messy alternative that can break the repo for everyone else using the same remote origin. Only consider it if you're the only one using it:

```
git reset --hard HEAD # undo that failed merge
git push --force      # replace everything remote with local
```

**Explanation** (now that I understand `git` better)
The reason this happened is because amending commits changes 'history'. Doing this locally is safe because it doesn't affect anyone else. However, amending commits that have already been pushed *does* affect other repos, and is not safe.

Comment: `man git-merge` provides an alternative in the section "How to resolve conflicts". `git merge --abort`

Answer (score 6):

Your GUI is probably just setting `--strategy=ours` (`git merge -s ours <branch>`). This will perform the merge, citing both commits as parents, but keep your entire directory state.

Your other option is to use `git merge -s recursive -X ours <branch>`, which will try to bring in files from both branches but will prefer your version whenever there is a conflict.

[Docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)

You can see the two different styles at work using the following demonstration shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir gittest
cd gittest
git init

git checkout master
echo "Line one" > bar
git add bar
git commit -m "Original commit"

git checkout -b fork1
echo "Line one and something" > bar
echo "Line two" > bam
git add bar bam
git commit -m "Fork1 commit."

git checkout master
git checkout -b fork2
echo "Line one and other stuff" > bar
echo "Line three" > baz
git add bar baz
git commit -m "Fork2 commit."

git checkout fork1
if [ "$1" = "ours" ]; then
  # `ls gittest` => bam bar
  # `cat gittest/bar` => Line one and something
  git merge -s ours fork2
else
  # `ls gittest` => bam bar baz
  # `cat gittest/bar` => Line one and something
  git merge -X ours fork2
fi
```

Comment: +1 for merge strategy. More good info on merge strategies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366860/when-would-you-use-the-different-git-merge-strategies

Comment: Side note: Also try `git merge -s recursive -X ours` to accept auto-merged changes but always use your local copy if there are conflicts.

Comment: Didn't work. I get:
error: 'merge' is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree,
hint: and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as
hint: appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit,
hint: or use 'git commit -a'.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.

Comment: @Kache, that looks like you're still in the middle of a merge, at which point you can't proceed without resolving all of your files. To cancel the merge, run `git reset --hard HEAD`, then try my steps. You can also try a demo script showing the two different "ours" strategies at http://pastebin.com/ScLzuHf7 .

Comment: Resetting like that would just put me back where I was, i.e. my local repo thinks everything is fine and updated. Anyway, I found the answer I needed and edited it into my question. I wanted to formally submit an answer, but they closed the question on me. =\

Comment: Ah, I understand how your method works now. It executes a merge from that `(working directory clean)` state. However, that means to do what I want, you'd have to `branch` or `stash` the current copy somewhere, so that you can cleanly `git merge` two clean branches.