# Is it possible to have a specific merge strategy just for 'git pull'

Tags: git, git-pull

The project I'm on has two branches, ostensibly named STABLE and DEV.

There's been some divergence in a core part of project between the two branches so when merging from Stable to DEV, we're using the `ours` merge strategy.

However, when pulling from Remote to DEV, we don't want to use the `ours` merge strategy, otherwise we'll not get the changes we need (if I understand merge strategies correctly)

So I guess the question is: is it possible to use one merge strategy when merging branches, and a different strategy when pulling from remote.

Or is my understanding of merge strategies all wrong?

Comment: yes, you can. For example i'm using currently  merge strategy to unify stable and dev branch (on stable branch i execute: git merge dev), but when i need update some change from stable on dev, i execute: git pull --rebase stable (it is a diferently merge strategy )

Comment: Are you asking whether your workflow makes sense or is your question about how to specify particular merge strategy in `git pull` command?

Comment: @kikicarbonell rebase is not a merge strategy; it's not a merge at all.

Comment: nop, but if you apply: git pull --rebase you have change from STABLE & DEV branch

Comment: I'm not up to speed with rebasing, i'll give that a look. @ArtemB, I'm asking how to specify particular merge strategy in git pull, and also have another merge strategy when merging branches.

Comment: @gargantaun `git pull` accepts the same `-s <strategy>` option that `git merge` does. Or you can do `git fetch origin` followed by `git merge` from upstream branch (or `git rebase` if you want) with whatever parameters you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When would you use the different git merge strategies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366860/when-would-you-use-the-different-git-merge-strategies)