# What exactly is a merge conflict?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have made a git repository and added a text file to it. This is 100% for learning purpose.

1. I added "1" to the text file and committed it to master.
2. Created a new branch from master and appended "2".
3. Finally, created a branch from master and appended "3".

Could you please explain how a conflict may occur in this, or any other, scenario?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You will have a conflict if you merge:

- `branch2` to `master` (no conflict)
- `branch3` to `master` (conflict):

That is because:

- The common ancestor would be `master` (with a second line empty)
- the source content is `branch3` (with a second line including "3")
- the destination content is on latest of `master` (with a second line including "2", from the merge of `branch2` to `master`)

Git will ask you to choose which content to keep ("3", "2", or both).

First, do the merges after:

```
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

See "[Fix merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7589612/6309)".

---

Notes:

- [With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64950077/6309), a new default merge strategy is in place:  **ORT** ("**Ostensibly Recursive's Twin**"), with [clearer conflict messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71330184/6309) (Gti 2.36, Q2 2022)
- you can *preview* those conflicts with ([Git 2.38, Q3 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73091924/6309)):

  ```
  git merge-tree --write-tree --no-messages branch1 branch2
  ```

  (That would not touch the index or working tree!)

Comment: I tried and got it. Thank you. So is it simply like if I add some new things it adds without any confusion/conflict, but if I am going to replace something it will cause confusion to replace it or keep original?

Comment: @user3693167 yes, because the same lines are modified twice, which triggers a manual resolution of the merge (conflict).

Comment: Thank you. Is it tracking it with line numbers ?

Comment: @user3693167 yes, in term of overlapping blocks of content (https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line) See also http://www.gitguys.com/topics/merging-with-a-conflict-conflicts-and-resolutions/

Comment: So the biggest thing about this answer is the following: git decides on where the conflict are taking into consideration the common ancestor.

Comment: @Dumoko Yes, it is a three-way merge (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4130766/6309), also shown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/31227165/6309

Comment: @VonC I get that they both changed the same code, but doesn't merge order defines which changes are applied? In this case changes by branch2 are overwritten by branch3.. Why is a conflict thrown? Is it because it is changed, and no new code is added? Or what exactly caused the conflict?

Comment: @Vin this is not about order, but about concurrent modifications done since the last common ancestor. Hence conflict.

Comment: @VonC, when you try to merge `branch2` to master, no conflicts will arise as you said. But why ? Both `master` and `branch2` changed the same file ? How does git decide what content to keep in merge - 1,2 or both ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed There is conflict only if common lines were modified concurrently. See "[Why is a 3-way merge advantageous over a 2-way merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130766/6309)" and "[While merging, does Git only consider the timestamp of a commit rather than which branch it belongs to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31227165/6309)".

Answer (score 42):

A merge conflict happens when two branches both modify the same region of a file and are subsequently merged. Git can't know which of the changes to keep, and thus needs human intervention to resolve the conflict.

In this case, your steps 2 and 3 create two branches that have conflicting changes.

Comment: What do you mean by "region"? How big are those?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. For text files, conflicts happen when two commits change the same line(s) in a file. I'm not sure how it works for binary files (e.g. images, sounds, etc.).

Comment: @GuillaumeF. infinitely big

Comment: @Caleb, can you explain what you mean by 'are subsequently merged' ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Let's say you've got a shared repo with some common branch C, and you and a friend each create your own branches. We'll call your branch D and your friend's branch E. You each proceed to modify the same part of the same file. Now when you try to merge D and E back into C, you'll find that the second merge will result in a conflict.

Answer (score 3):

I understand this is an old question but in case you would like to know in an intuitive way the algorithms used by Git to compare two files.It will clarify the doubts on how overlapping regions works with diff.

Here is an explanation of one of the popular algorithms which was developed by Eugene W. Myers. In this approach  finding the shortest edit script (SES) is modelled as a graph search.
Here is **really good article by James Coglan on the same with an example** - [The Myers diff algorithm](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2017/02/12/the-myers-diff-algorithm-part-1/)