# Overwrite everything in master with another branch in git

Tags: git

I have a very out of date `master` branch in a git repository.

All of my work has been done in another branch.

What is the best way to merge the two?

I don't care about anything in `master`, it is way out of date.

Comment: Did `git checkout master && git pull && git merge <your-branch>` not take?

Comment: It deviated from the whole point of having distributed version control to a centralized version control system,  It is MERGE not Override. [ PR - Pull request ]

Answer (score 13):

If you are fine with losing the history of your master branch you just let `master` point to the head of your current branch (your don't "overwrite" `master` - the branch - per se):

```
git checkout yourotherbranch
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master
```

Of course if you have a remote clone, you'll then have to

```
git push -f origin master
```

**Nota bene**: this *specifically* applies to replacing the whole of your `master` branch and throwing the old `master` away as the title suggests. 
Otherwise, you should be fine with `git merge master --strategy=ours`.

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging the alternative - I would imagine that a merge would do fine, but if they wanted to replace the entire history, then that's another matter entirely.

Answer (score 13):

Let's assume your work is in a branch called `dev`:

```
git checkout dev 
git merge --strategy=ours master
git checkout master 
git merge dev
```

The merge option `--strategy=ours` *is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches* ([quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366860/when-would-you-use-the-different-git-merge-strategies)).

Comment: This is not enough.
ours strategy work on conflicts when there are files on master not existing on dev that is not covered.

Answer (score 6):

Lots of these questions are answered with the `git merge strategy=ours` solution, but I think it misses the point of the question. I interpret the question as "i didn't follow good practice and basically the master is useless, and i want nothing from the master". common for solo projects.

`git push -f origin branch_ive_been_working_for_months:master` fully replaces your remote master with your remote branch. then, just `git pull origin master` after locally checking out master is the solution that directly answers question IMO.

Comment: This is the most succinct answer, fulfilling exactly the intent of the original poster.

Answer (score 3):

A complete overwrite isn't merging the other content, it's abandoning it.

```
git checkout -B master anotherbranch
```

This has the advantage over a delete-and-recreate of retaining your branch settings and reflogs.

If there's some administrative requirement to retain worthless commits in your history, follow that with `git merge -s ours master@{1}`. I prefer this sequence because it generates an unusual merge message, which will alert scanning `--oneline` logs that the merge is unusual.

Comment: I think @JoeAC overlooked this gem when he commented that Azeli's answer was the only one that fulfills the intent of the poster. This preserves history while obliterating the contents of the main/master branch. The nota bene regarding the "unusual merge message" is a masterful touch.