# Git Overwrite master with branch

Tags: git

I want to overrite master with a particular branch after making changes to it, what I done to do it is:

Step 1: Checkout brranch from Git, using command :

```
git checkout branch_name
```

Step 2: I done some changes in code, now I want to make this branch as master, for that I first run the command:

```
git status
```

Above command list me all the modified files.

Now my question, what all I need to do overrite master with this particular branch "my_branch"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870328/overwrite-everything-in-master-with-another-branch-in-git/ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870328/overwrite-everything-in-master-with-another-branch-in-git/ solved half a problem, but when I performing git pull from another system, I am still getting the previous version.

Comment: @Arpit, well, if you don't push it to the remote system that's the way it will stay. Be aware that this requires a force push, which your teammates may or may not appreciate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overwrite everything in master with another branch in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870328/overwrite-everything-in-master-with-another-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

`git branch -f master dev_branch` will rewrite local master branch.

`git push remote +dev_branch:master` will rewrite remote branch.

- NOTE: If the above doesn't work, the name `remote` could be `origin` for you (i.e. `git push origin +dev_branch:master`)

Comment: For me `git push origin +dev_branch:master` worked. Thx!

Comment: Getting: `fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: `remote` here means your remote. Most likely `origin`.

Comment: git branch -f master dev_branch - This command gave me no error but did not merge the branch to master, when I saw the diff it says no change

Comment: It doesn't merge and there would be no difference. The only thing this command does is "delete" your master branch and "create" it again pointing to a different commit.

Comment: @aragaer - Will the history from the master branch will be deleted?

Comment: Nothing will be deleted immediately - but master branch will be pointing to a completely different commit. So... basically yes.

Comment: If you get `fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.` make sure to move out of `master` branch

Comment: This worked even when `master` and `dev_branch` had different histories.

Comment: Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,

I am getting this error.

Comment: That is not an error, that's just a message. Commands above will work in any case.

Answer (score 51):

To completely replace the `master` branch with the contents of any other `feature_branch` you can also use:

```
git checkout feature_branch
git merge -s ours --no-commit master
git commit      # Add a message regarding the replacement that you just did
git checkout master
git merge feature_branch
```

See: http://git.tutorialhorizon.com/2014/10/05/replace-the-master-branch-with-another-branch-in-git/

Comment: This isn't working for me.   I just get the 'Already up to date' message, without anything really changing in the repo.

Comment: nm - it works.   Just had to do a push at the end to update the remote repo.  Thanks!

Comment: For me, after I merge my feature branch with -s ours, I get all the unwanted commits from master onto my feature branch. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: the mess I created with git, finally got resolved by this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Fixed it for me. :)

Comment: When a git workflow works, is elegant, and make sense ;) Thanks for that. Exactly what I was looking for.