# How to replace the content of master branch with the content of other branch

Tags: git

I have a master branch.
Then, I have an updated branch.
How can I totally replace the content of master branch with the content of updated branch?
I tried simple merge

```
git checkout master
git merge updated
```

The content of master branch wasn't updated.

Comment: Do you want to replace the history too? If not, do you want to make a merge commit or a single squash-style commit?

Comment: See [Git Overwrite master with branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105210/git-overwrite-master-with-branch). You can also have a separate commit where you remove everything from the master branch and *then* merge your `updated` branch into it.