# resolve over 500 conflicts files in GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, github, terminal, github-desktop

We have two branches. staging and production, we made many changes in the branches including new files names. now I tried to `git merge -` but I get this error.

[image]

is there any command line in terminal to resolve the conflicts with replacing the production with staging?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to keep the past history of production, before replacing it with staging content, I would [use a 2 step merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29870384/6309)

```
git checkout staging
git merge --strategy=ours production
git checkout production
git merge staging
git push
```

That way:

- the first merge changes nothing on staging
- the second merge is a trivial one, with production HEAD simply moving (fast-forward) to staging HEAD