# How do I merge multiple branches without commiting?

Tags: git, git-merge

Is it possible? I'm able to merge one branch using --no-commit, but when try to merge another one it said that I haven't concluded my current merge.

How can I conclude it without commiting it?

Comment: This is mostly just curiosity, because Git *can* do that (in some cases) via "octopus" merge as already answered, but: why do you *want* this?  Some VCSes (e.g., Mercurial) cannot do this at all, and that's OK: they lose no power because any octopus merge can be done with repeated pairwise merge.  I'm wondering why people find octopus merge attractive.

Answer (score 3):

If your merges definitely won't require any manual intervention (no conflicts), then you should use the [Octopus merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_options). You would use it like this, assuming you are on `master` and want to merge other branches is:

```
git merge some_branch other_branch third_branch
```

This [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/366940/1431750) has a good explanation.

You cannot continue merging in other branches in different steps without committing first.

You could also try using the `--squash` option to prevent creating the commit/postpone it to the next merge but it will make the git history look a bit strange.