# git merge --strategy vs. --strategy-option

Tags: git, git-merge

What is the difference between the git merge option
`--strategy-option` (short `-X`)
and
`--strategy` (short `-s`)?

There are a lot of questions regarding [merge strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366860/when-would-you-use-the-different-git-merge-strategies). But none explain the difference between these options.

Also the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) is not helpful:

> --strategy-option Pass merge strategy specific option through to the merge strategy.

Comment: A strategy option is like a sub strategy. Taking `recursive` for example, two of its options are `ours` and `theirs`. One option makes the strategy works in a specific way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TL;DR: `-s` is for specifying a merge strategy `-X` is for supplying options for said strategy.

The git documentation says:

```
-s <strategy>
--strategy=<strategy>
```

Use the given merge strategy; can be supplied more than once to specify them in the order they should be tried. If there is no -s option, a built-in list of strategies is used instead (git merge-recursive when merging a single head, git merge-octopus otherwise).

```
-X <option>
--strategy-option=<option>
```

Pass merge strategy specific option through to the merge strategy.

Additionally, further down the chapter MERGE STRATEGIES explains all the available strategies and their options.

Comment: I like to say that `-X` stands for `eXtend`, as in *add more options to the strategy you choose.* Essentially, I believe that the *names* "strategy" and "strategy-option" are inherently confusing, but "strategy" and "eXtended option *to/for* strategy" are at least a little bit less so.

Answer (score 0):

The merge allows the backend 'merge strategies' to be chosen with `-s` option. Some strategies can also take their own options, which can be passed by giving -X arguments to 'git-merge' and/or 'git-pull'.

On a very high level, the following are supported in the strategy option from 1.7

- resolve
- recursive

  - ours
  - theirs
  - subtree[=path]
- octopus
- ours
- subtree

For details refer to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies/1.7.0)

Comment: Please provide a more useful answer! The contents of your answer are directly taken from the official documentation.