# git sparse checkout - can't abort merge

Tags: git, git-sparse-checkout

Using git 2.25.1 
Used git sparse-checkout init/set to setup sparsecheckout.

Now I'm in situation that i need to abort merge.

Tried:

```
git merge --abort
```

**Entry 'QStreams_xxx/infra/QPrism/Qpvc/gradle_pvc/gradle_pvc.iml' not uptodate.
    Cannot update sparse checkout.
    fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'**

Tried:

```
git reset --hard
```

**Same error message.**

Tried to disable sparse-checkout

```
git sparse-checkout disable
```

Error:

**error: cannot disable sparse-checkout: You have unstaged changes.**
   **error: additionally, your index contains uncommitted changes.**

In there any way out of this ?

Thanks
Boaz

Comment: Can you somehow recreate a minimal example that reproduces this? I tried recreating sparse-checkout merge conflicts and then aborting and it seems to work

Comment: @Omer You are right, I tried to reproduce simple conflict on folder that it not covered by sparse-checkout rules, and --abort works.Will try to investigate my case maybe it is more complicated than I thought

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best flow, but a least it lets me some way out ...

```
git read-tree --restore HEAD
#now usual cleanup
git restore .
git clean -xdf
```

Answer (score 0):

The merge should be more robust with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021): various mergy operations have been prepared to work efficiently with the sparse index.

This is especially true with the new (and default) [merge strategy ORT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64950077/6309) ("Ostensibly Recursive's Twin", which will be the default one with Git 2.34, Q4 2021).

See [commit 516680b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/516680ba7704c473bb21628aa19cabbd787df4db), [commit 5d9c934](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d9c9349bd0acda149f37eb1c5edc2a5ef747eea), [commit c0b9930](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0b99303db317894dc49398cd3e2db4ef02e8dcf), [commit 6957636](https://github.com/git/git/commit/695763679210420656f4125d9706bba25c76ae4b), [commit a338063](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a33806398a418289388ad992e385a314b4b10225), [commit ad90da7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad90da73513d7b0055e47c6918e1d75c6165fa69) (08 Sep 2021) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a16dd13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a16dd1374023d1a5f6ee7c48661e0ed53a954391), 20 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`merge`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a33806398a418289388ad992e385a314b4b10225): make sparse-aware with ORT
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> Allow '[`git merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a33806398a418289388ad992e385a314b4b10225/Documentation/git-merge.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup> to operate without expanding a sparse index, at least not immediately.
> The index still will be expanded in a few cases:
>
> 1. If the merge strategy is 'recursive', then we enable
>    command_requires_full_index at the start of the merge_recursive()
>    method. We expect sparse-index users to also have the 'ort' strategy
>    enabled.
> 2. With the 'ort' strategy, if the merge results in a conflicted file,
>    then we expand the index before updating the working tree. The loop
>    that iterates over the worktree replaces index entries and tracks
>    '`original_cache_nr`' which can become completely wrong if the index
>    expands in the middle of the operation. This safety valve is
>    important before that loop starts. A later change will focus this
>    to only expand if we indeed have a conflict outside of the
>    sparse-checkout cone.
> 3. Other merge strategies are executed as a `git merge-X subcommand`,
>    and those strategies are currently protected with the
>    'command_requires_full_index' guard.
>
> Some test updates are required, including a mistaken '[`git checkout -b`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a33806398a418289388ad992e385a314b4b10225/Documentation/git-checkout.txt#L147)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--bltnew_branchgt))</sup> that did not specify the base branch, causing merges to be fast-forward merges.