# Create copy of file on github repo but use it for different content

Tags: github, git-merge, github-for-windows

I have a file in github called test1.py

I want to use all of its content and just change 1 line. So i created a new branch, copied test1.py, then deleted test1.py, and then pasted it in a different location in the same repo. Then renamed it to test2.py. Then changed 1 line.

Then what I wanted is to merge master with my branch.

So when I tried that , github thinks that test1.py is the same as test2.py and it is just moved to a different location, and i get a merge conflict(because of the 1 changed  line )

How can I avoid that github sees test2.py like it us test1.py?

I explained above ,

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you might want to *keep* `test1.py` in your new branch, and duplicate it in `test2.py`.

That way, the merge from master won't think `test2.py` is `test1.py` renamed.

The other option is to use the [`no-rename`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-no-renames) option to a merge strategy which takes that option into account:

```
git merge -s recursive -X no-renames
```

As noted by [IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75656609/create-copy-of-file-on-github-repo-but-use-it-for-different-content/75659803?noredirect=1#comment133478990_75659803), the default merge strategy ORT (introduced with [Git 2.30, Q1 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64950077/6309)) would ignore that option.

Comment: Nitpick: `-X no-renames` specifies an _option_ to the merge strategy, not a strategy itself. Also, if I'm reading the manual right, it is ignored by the "ort" strategy, which is now the default, so you would need to also specify the "recursive" strategy, as in `git merge -s recursive -X no-renames`

Comment: @IMSoP Good point, thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I will try option 2 tomorrow. Your first approach seems also good but in my case I already have 2 branches as described above , so keeping the test1.py is not possible anymore. I can't vote up this answer cause I have a new account unfortunately